# Computing coordinate numbers in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw three congruent, equilateral triangles unicursally in TikZ (see figure below). Per se, this is rather simple, but I want to write the TikZ code so that I can easily change the shape of the figure by adjusting a few geometrical parameters. More specifically, I want the coordinates in the TikZ figure to vary, depending on the value of the parameters.

[image: three unicursal, congruent, equilateral triangles]

The two parameters I want to change are the distances from *a* to *q* (later referred to as *L*) and from *q* to *b* (later referred to as *Δ*) in the figure above. By choosing *a* to be the origin, the expressions for the coordinates will be as follows

*a*: `( 0 , 0 )`
*b*: `( cos(60°)*(L + Δ) , sin(60°)*(L + Δ) )`
*c*: `( bx + cos(60°)*L , by - sin(60°)*L )`
*d*: `( L - cx , cy )`
*e*: `( L - bx, by )`
*f*: `( L , 0 )`

where *bx*, *by*, *cx* and *cy* denote the *x* and *y* coordinates of points *b* and *c* respectively. *(The coordinates of* q *are not necessary in order to draw the figure.)*

I tried the following approach, but this gives the output shown below, where only the coordinates of *a* and *f* are correct. If this had worked, I would be able to simply change the definitions of `\l` and `\delta` and recompile to see how the geometry changes with *L* and *Δ*.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\cossixty{0.5}
\def\sinsixty{0.866025}

\def\l{6}
\def\delta{2}
\def\ldelta{\l+\delta}
\def\bx{\cossixty*\ldelta}
\def\by{\sinsixty*\ldelta}
\def\cx{\bx+\cossixty*\l}
\def\cy{\by-\sinsixty*\l}
\def\dx{\l-\cx}
\def\ex{\l-\bx}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (\bx,\by);
\coordinate (c) at (\cx,\cy);
\coordinate (d) at (\dx,\cy);
\coordinate (e) at (\ex,\by);
\coordinate (f) at (\l,0);

\begin{scope}[thick]
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (a);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: erroneous output]

So my question is this: how can I make TikZ compute the coordinate expressions listed above into floating point numbers and get the correct output?

*(This is only a small part of a larger image which I am to make in TikZ, so there is, of course, a good reason why I choose to draw the figure unicursally, and with adjustable parameters.)*

Comment: You can't do this with TikZ `intersection` functionality?

Comment: @Seamus I don't see how I can do this. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You code works just fine once you let `pgf` do the math for you:

[image]

### Notes:

- `\delta` is a greek letter so better to use a different name.
- I also added a `node` to label the two parameters.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\l{4}
\def\MyDelta{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ldelta{\l+\MyDelta}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bx{cos(60)*\ldelta}
\pgfmathsetmacro\by{sin(60)*\ldelta}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cx{\bx+cos(60)*\l}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cy{\by-sin(60)*\l}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dx{\l-\cx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ex{\l-\bx}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (\bx,\by);
\coordinate (c) at (\cx,\cy);
\coordinate (d) at (\dx,\cy);
\coordinate (e) at (\ex,\by);
\coordinate (f) at (\l,0);

\begin{scope}[thick]
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (a)
        node [below, midway] {$l = \l, \Delta = \MyDelta$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the solution was rather simple. Do you know why the `\def` command did not give the intended output?

Comment: @eiterorm: I don't think LaTeX can do complex math by itself. You can include the `calc` package and do some rudimentary math, but that was not enough for this use.  I did not try to use `\numepxr <calculation> \relax`. I just always use `\pgfmathsetmcro{}{}`. See [What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-defining-a-tikz-constant/) for reference.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the fun of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\qadist{3cm}
\def\qbshift{1cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{\qadist/sin(60)}
\tikzset{equilatri/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,
                           draw, anchor=corner 2,minimum height=\myheight
                           }
         }
\node[equilatri] (a) {};
\node[equilatri] at ([shift={(60:\qbshift)}]a.corner 2) (b) {};
\node[equilatri] at ([shift={(120:\qbshift)}]a.corner 2) (c) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and a little more compact with the same output

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\l{3}
\def\d{1}
\draw (0,0) -- (60:\l+\d) -- ++(-60:\l) -- ++({-(\l+\d)},0) -- ++(60:\l) -- ++(-60:\l+\d) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several others possibilities to create to compute the coordinates. It's possible to make calculations without defines variables. To get the final pictures, I prefer avoid nodes because it's difficult to scale the whole picture if you mix drawing and text. The only problem is to name the points used in the picture.

**A)** first idea : we create a macro to build an equilateral triangle. The second argument is used to place the new triangle. It's `\Delta` and an angle. The first argument is the length of a side. All the coordinates are a,b and c. I used `\pgfnodealias` to rename the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\equi[2]{%
     \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]  
         \draw (0,0)   coordinate (a)
                    -- (0:#1)  coordinate (b) 
                    -- (60:#1) coordinate (c)--cycle; 
     \end{scope}
} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\equi{6}{0:0}  \node[below] at (a){a} ; 
\equi{6}{60:2}
\pgfnodealias{e}{a} 
 \node[below right] at (e){e} ;  
\equi{6}{120:2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**B)**  It's like percusse's solution but I use a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \newcommand\equilatri[2]{%
    \draw (0,0) -- (60:#1+#2)
                -- ++(-60:#1) 
                -- ++(0:-#1-#2)
                -- ++(60:#1)
                -- ++(-60:#1+#2)  
                --  cycle;
   \node [below] at (0:#1/2) {$l = #1, \Delta = #2$}; 
        } 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[thick,red]
\equilatri{4}{2}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[thick,xshift=6cm,blue]
\equilatri{6}{1}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]