# Define a New Macro via a Macro Using xparse Syntax

Tags: macros, conditionals, xparse

I am trying to set up a macro that defines a macro that is to be executed only once.

With what I learned from [Define a Macro via Macro if Given Macro is not defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined) I can do that via the `\expandafter\newcommand` syntax. And indeed the MWE as below works and produces the desired output:

[image]

where the subsequent `\HelloWorld` and `\HelloDude` are ignored.

What I would like to do, is to learn how to use `\NewDocumentCommand` (instead of `\newcommand`) to define this new macro via a macro.
My attempt (requires you to *uncomment* the `\def` at the top of the file)  fails with

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a

Furthermore, am wondering if there is a way to define repeated parameters. That is instead of `{m m}` can I use something similar to with `tabular` where one can say `\begin{tabular}{r*{3}{l}r}` which is the identical to `\begin{tabular}{rlllr}`.
This would save me from having to use `\IfEqCase`for each possible number of parameters. I personally only need up to 3 so am ok with the slight duplication of code below, but though I'd ask in case there was some other syntax that I am not aware of.

### Notes:

- You need to *uncomment* the `\def` at the top to get the MWE below to fail.

### Refernces

- [Define a Macro via Macro if Given Macro is not defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined)
- [Defining Extensible macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115017/defining-extensible-macros)

### Code:

```
%% Uncomment the following \def to get the failing test case.
%\def\UseXparseForDefiningMacro{}% Works if commented out (in which case \newcommand{}{} is used to define macro)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce}{m m m}{%
    % #1 = csname to use
    % #2 = number of parameters
    % #3 = code to execute
    \newtoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}%
    \togglefalse{AlreadyIssued#1}%
    \ifdefined\UseXparseForDefiningMacro
        \IfEqCase{#2}{%
            {0}{\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{     }{% No paramater version
                    \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                        #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                        \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
                    }%
                }}%
            {1}{\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{  m  }{% 1 paramater version
                    \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                        #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                        \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
                    }%
                }}%
            {2}{\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{ m m }{% 2 paramater version
                    \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                        #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                        \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
                    }%
                }}%
        }%
    \else% ---------------------------------------------  This works!!
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[#2]{%
            \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
            }%
        }%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce{HelloWorld}{0}{% Does not take any parameters
    Hello World!%
}

\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce{HelloDude}{1}{% Take 1 parameter
    Hello \textcolor{red}{#1}.%
}

\begin{document}

%% Section 1: Works if \UseXparseForDefiningMacro is NOT defined
\HelloWorld
\HelloWorld

%% Section 2: Works if \UseXparseForDefiningMacro is NOT defined
\HelloDude{Peter}
\HelloDude{John}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use the `expl3` syntax? It makes much more sense when using `xparse`, in my opinion.  I would imagine the solution would also be more concise.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Am embarrassed to admit it, but I can't quite read `expl3` syntax yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this but it's so wrong, why mix expl3 and etoolbox tests and why all the toggle stuff, if you want `\foo` to just execute once define it to be

```
 \def\foo{hello\let\foo\@empty}
```

No need for a separate toggle macro.

but anyway:

```
%% Uncomment the following \def to get the failing test case.
\def\UseXparseForDefiningMacro{}% Works if commented out (in which case \newcommand{}{} is used to define macro)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce}{m m m}{%
    % #1 = csname to use
    % #2 = number of parameters
    % #3 = code to execute
    \newtoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}%
    \togglefalse{AlreadyIssued#1}%
    \ifdefined\UseXparseForDefiningMacro
        \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
              \expandafter{\romannumeral#2000}{%
            \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
            }%
        }%
    \else% ---------------------------------------------  This works!!
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[#2]{%
            \iftoggle{AlreadyIssued#1}{}{%
                #3%                           Never executed this macro so go ahead an execute it,
                \toggletrue{AlreadyIssued#1}% and remember that we did (so we don't do it again).
            }%
        }%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce{HelloWorld}{0}{% Does not take any parameters
    Hello World!%
}

\DefineMeAMacroThatExecutesOnlyOnce{HelloDude}{1}{% Take 1 parameter
    Hello \textcolor{red}{#1}.%
}

\begin{document}

%% Section 1: Works if \UseXparseForDefiningMacro is NOT defined
\HelloWorld
\HelloWorld

%% Section 2: Works if \UseXparseForDefiningMacro is NOT defined
\HelloDude{Peter}
\HelloDude{John}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about the `\def` thing to stop things from happening again. Can you elaborate on the `\expandafter{\romannumeral#2000}` magic that is happening here. How does that become `m m` if `#2=2`?

Comment: `\romannumeral2000` expands to `mm`

Comment: @egreg: Wow, that is very clever!! An I was thinking that  a loop would be needed...

Comment: @PeterGrill yes well it was fortunate you wanted `m` arguments (although using romannumeral and then changing `m` to whatever you need is a viable technique for replicating in general)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution for this problem, using (perhaps abusing) only `expl3` features. I'm not really sure about the usefulness of this code. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewOnceMacro}{m m m}
 {
  \grill_new_once_macro:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }

% an addition to the kernel functions
\cs_set_eq:NN \use_none: \prg_do_nothing:

\cs_new_protected:Npn \grill_new_once_macro:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc
   {% the corresponding "do nothing" macro
    \cs_to_str:N #1 -disabled
   }
   {% generate \use_none:<as many n's as #2>
    use_none: \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { n }
   }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:n { \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } }
      { \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { m } } % the right number of m's
   }
   {
    % the first usage definition
    #3
    % then redefine the macro to do nothing
    \cs_gset_eq:Nc #1 { \cs_to_str:N #1 -disabled }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewOnceMacro{\HelloWorld}{0}{Hello world}
\NewOnceMacro{\Hello}{1}{Hello #1}
\NewOnceMacro{\Foo}{2}{Your #1 is full of #2}

\begin{document}

\HelloWorld
\HelloWorld

\Hello{Peter}
\Hello{Grill}

\Foo{hovercraft}{eels}
\Foo{head}{ideas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read in `interface3` about `\use:x` “Any hash characters (#) in the argument must be doubled.” What does that mean?

Comment: @Manuel I'm not really using `#` inside `\use:x`, because `#1` and `#2` will be replaced with the arguments before `\use:x` is executed. Think to it as doing a `\def` inside a `\def`: if you want to use parameters to the inner `\def` you have to double `#`.

Comment: Okey, but then why is necessary that comment? Isn't that applied to every command? -- EDIT: Understood.

Comment: *I will not upvote this question, it is scratched.* `:P`