# How can I force expansion within this optional argument?

Tags: expansion

<sup>Oh look, a real question!</sup>

In trying to actually [complete something](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188052/17423), I came across the following limitation of this lambda macro creator: it apparently does not work in the use case it was intended for.  It's certainly a problem with expansion control, but I don't know where to really start.

```
\documentclass{article}

% (David Carlisle / @Manuel)'s much simpler version
\newcommand\LambdaFunction[2][0]{%
  \let\tmp\relax
  \newcommand\tmp[#1]{#2}\tmp}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[
  box={\LambdaFunction{%
      \colorbox
      {myblue}%
      {\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}%
    }%
  }
  ]{align*}
  a   &= b   \\
  a^2 &= b^2
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should note that I am very much open to using `expl3`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed out the color package:-) also my version defaulted to [0] rather than [1] so I had to add [1]. Then you need to double `#` just because.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

% (David Carlisle / @Manuel)'s much simpler version
\newcommand\LambdaFunction[2][0]{%
  \let\tmp\relax
  \newcommand\tmp[#1]{#2}\tmp}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[
  box={\LambdaFunction[1]{%
      \colorbox
      {blue}%
      {\hspace{1em}##1\hspace{1em}}%
    }%
  }
  ]{align*}
  a   &= b   \\
  a^2 &= b^2
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm just not having a good day, today XD Thanks!

Comment: However, having a `[0]` by default doesn't make any sense, since the idea is that it has arguments. If you don't need arguments you could just put the code without worrying about this `\LamdaFunction`.

Comment: @Manuel yes true I just did it for consistency with every other latex command definition but you can change `[0]` to `[1]` but actually I'd just make it mandatory.