# Manipulate Length in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using tikz package to make nice schemes presenting my work, and I am confronted to a little problem: manipulating variables.

I can do this the hard way:

For exemple let's say that I want to draw a rectangle (8*4),

```
%Defining nodes for geometry
\coordinate (left_minus) at (-4,-2) ;
\coordinate (left_plus) at (-4,2) ;
\coordinate (right_minus) at (4,-2) ;
\coordinate (right_plus) at (4,2) ;

%Drawing rectangle
\draw[line width= 1pt, fill=green!30] (left_minus) rectangle (right_plus)
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
\newcommand{\Length}{8}
\newcommand{\Width}{4}
\coordinate (left_minus) at (-Length/2,-Width/2) ;
\coordinate (left_plus) at (-Length/2,Width/2) ;
```

I browsed the web but wasn't able to find something useful about manipulating variables in LaTeX. Do you guys have any idea about how I should proceed?

Thanks!

Aubry

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related question: [What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47178/4918) …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach should work (at least in TikZ) but you must use the macro names with a leading backslash `\`

```
\newcommand{\Length}{8}
\newcommand{\Width}{4}
\coordinate (left_minus) at (-\Length/2,-\Width/2) ;
\coordinate (left_plus) at (-\Length/2,\Width/2) ;
```

The **shorter way** I use usually is a `\def` **inside** of a `{tikzpicture}`. In this case the “lengthen” are simple macros in the sense of TeX and can be pares by TikZ as if you type them directly, i.e. (0,0.5*\h) would be the same as (0,0.5*2) but also (0,0.5\h) would be read as (0,0.25) so don’t omit the `*` sign. I use this way since it depends on the current setting of the basis vectors of `TikZ`. The drawback of `\def` is that it overwirtes existing macros but if you use it inside of `{tikzpicture}` the (re)definition is kept local and should be no problem. If you want to use the varaibales globally you may use `\newcommand` and longer variable names instead.

[image: shorter way]

The **longer way** uses really TeX lengthen, which can be used everywhere you need a length, e.g. in `\hspace`. But in this case you must add a unit and the lengthen won’t change when the basis vectors change.

[image: longer way]

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{short way}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\l{5}
    \def\h{2}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.5*\l,\h/2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
    \def\l{5}
    \def\h{2}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.5*\l,\h/2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{longer way}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{5cm}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.5\mylength,\myheight/2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.5\mylength,\myheight/2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so obvious that I feel kind of stupid right now.

Comment: This happens to all of use ;-) See my edit for some more information.

Comment: The TeX.SE way to thank someone for an answer is to accept it (and vote it up). And there's no need to feel stupid.