# tikz, How to define a constant and then use it in drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

For example I would like to do something like this

```
r=2
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,{2*r}) ellipse ({sqrt(r)} and {8/r});
    \draw (0,{r}) ellipse ({sqrt(r/2)} and {4/r});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where everywhere `r` is seen in the above tikz commands, it is replaced by its defined value. I cannot seem to find a way to conveniently do this, I am sure I am just not looking in the right place

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One option, `\def`ining `\ra`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\def\ra{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,{2*\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra)} and {8/\ra});
    \draw (0,{\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra/2)} and {4/\ra});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could use instead a (La)TeX length, via `\newlength`, `\setlength` and the appropriate syntax for lengths operations but using a length register for this simple application is not really necessary.

Comment: Note on `\def`, it does roughly speaking "text substitution" so if you have e.g. `\def\a{1+2} \def\b{\a*2}` prepare for surprises. Also the value is recomputed every time, use pgfmathsetmacro is better

Answer (score 18):

Or go the `pgf` way by defining

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ra}{2}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ra}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,{2*\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra)} and {8/\ra});
    \draw (0,{\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra/2)} and {4/\ra});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `pgfkeys` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  ra/.store in=\ra,
  ra=0   %% initial value, set to anything so that even if you don't specify a value later, it compiles
   }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ra=2]   %% set it here, if not set, initial value 0 is taken
    \draw (0,{2*\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra)} and {8/\ra});
    \draw (0,{\ra}) ellipse ({sqrt(\ra/2)} and {4/\ra});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, ra/.store in=\ra, ra=0}` can be shortened as `\tikzset{ra/.store in=\ra, ra=0}`. For other packages based on `pgfkeys`, the path before `.cd` in your solution or the shortcut command I just mentioned generally needs to be adapted (otherwise, problems as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505708/73317) may arise). For example, with `pgfplots`, one would use either `\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/.cd, ra/.store in=\ra, ra=0}` or `\pgfplotsset{ra/.store in=\ra, ra=0}`. The version with `\pgfplotsset` is probably more “idiomatic.”