# pgfplots: How to define a key and set its value?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

Why does setting the value of key `alpha=0.5` inside `semilogxaxis` options (i.e. `\begin{semilogxaxis}[alph=0.5]`) not take effect

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
        alph/.store in=\alph,
        alph=1
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time) = \time^(\alph-1);}]
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[alph=0.5]
    \addplot[domain = 1e-6 : 1e6, samples = 100] {CFDfixedalph(x)};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

unlike setting the value inside `tikzpicture` options (i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time) = \time^(\alph-1);},alph=0.5]`)?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll rename your `\alph` macro to `\alphstore` because I am a coward and fear that redefining LaTeX's `\alph` command, even locally, might have undesirable side effects in some cases.

## Background and analysis

`pgfkeys` implements namespaces<sup>1</sup> using its filesystem-like key hierarchy. When you use a package based on `pgfkeys` (e.g., `tikz`, `pgfplots`, `forest`, `tikz-cd`, `tcolorbox`...) and pass a key to a command or environment of this package without specifying the full path of the key, it is typically looked for using a *default path* for the package. For `tikz`, the default path is `/tikz`; for `forest`, `/forest`; for `tikz-cd`, `/tikz/commutative diagrams`; for `tcolorbox`, `/tcb`; and for `pgfplots`, it is `/pgfplots`.

Your code:

```latex
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  alph/.store in=\alphstore,
  alph=1
}
```

defines and calls the key `/tikz/alph` because of the `/tikz/.cd`.<sup>2</sup> When you do:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = { ... }, alph=0.5]
```

`alph=0.5` is processed by a command obtained from `\begin{tikzpicture}`. This is a Ti*k*Z command, therefore since your key `alph` isn't given with a full path, it is looked for in `/tikz`.  In other words, the full path becomes `/tikz/alph`. This is the key you have defined, thus it can be run without any problem. However, when you do:

```latex
\begin{semilogxaxis}[alph=0.5]
```

things are a bit different. The command that processes `alph=0.5` doesn't belong to Ti*k*Z, rather it belongs to `pgfplots`. Thus, it works with keys in `/pgfplots`. In this case, the key `/tikz/alph` *is* executed, but apparently too late for the plot.<sup>3</sup>

## Suggested fix

In order to fix the problem, simply define your `alph` key in a place that `pgfplots` considers when preparing the plot, like this:

```latex
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/.cd,
    alph/.store in=\alphstore,
    alph=1
}
```

Actually, there is a shortcut for this, which is `\pgfplotsset{alph/.store in=\alphstore, alph=1}`. `\pgfplotsset` is to `pgfplots` what `\tikzset` is to Ti*k*Z, `\tikzcdset` to `tikz-cd`, `\forestset` to `forest`, `\tcbset` to `tcolorbox`, etc. Thanks to these `\...set` macros, you don't need to remember the prefix for each package by heart, but recall that there is more or less always a `\...set` macro that starts with the package name—for packages based on `pgfkeys`. This macro is usually quite useful for customizing things related to the considered package.

Your example with this change:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{alph/.store in=\alphstore, alph=1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time) = \time^(\alphstore-1);}]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[alph=0.5]
\addplot[domain = 1e-6 : 1e6, samples = 100] {CFDfixedalph(x)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Other technique

Another way to do the same is to define `/pgfplots/alph` as a key that directly stores a value (as opposed to a key that stores code to be executed, which is what the `.store in` handler creates). This is maybe more in the `pgfkeys` spirit, but also significantly more verbose where you need to recover the value of the key (`\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/alph}`). That said, you can use a shortcut macro such as the `\getalph` macro in the following example to circumvent this verbosity problem, so this is probably a good solution too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{alph/.initial=1}
\newcommand*{\getalph}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/alph}} % convenient shortcut

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time) = \time^(\getalph-1); } ]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[alph=0.5]
\addplot[domain = 1e-6 : 1e6, samples = 100] {CFDfixedalph(x)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Footnotes**

1. A term used when talking about programming languages.
2. `cd` stands for “change directory”. This is in analogy with filesystems; for instance, in many shells (POSIX, MS-DOS...), the `cd` command is used to change the current directory. `/tikz/.cd` tells `pgfkeys` to go to the `/tikz` “directory” (it is not a real filesystem directory; the whole `pgfkeys` directory hierarchy is only a tree-like structure held *in memory*). This new “current directory” (default path in `pgfkeys` terminology) will stay in effect until the next `.cd` (a nested call to `\pgfkeys` could also change it, but only inside the nested call). This causes subsequent relative paths to keys to be resolved using this path. For instance, `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, line width=2pt, line cap=round}` is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{/tikz/line width=2pt, /tikz/line cap=round}`.
3. This causes the following message to be printed:

   > Package `pgfplots` Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is `[1.0000000000:1.0000000000]`) on input line 14.

Comment: Carefully and comprehensively explained. One final naive question if you don't mind: what is the meaning of `.cd` in both `/tikz/.cd` and `/pgfplots/.cd`? Additionally, is there a better and more brief way to define keys instead of what I did? Since I only copied and pasted this piece of code from old answer.

Comment: @frougon you should add a comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235504/120578

Comment: @Diaa The `.cd` is a `pgfkeys` handler, it is described under *Handlers for Path Management* in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (about p. 964). 〈key〉`/.cd` causes the default path to be set to 〈key〉 (default path which is reset to `/` at the beginning of each call to `\pgfkeys`). The *default path* is what is automatically prepended by `\pgfkeys` when you don't specify a full path for a key, as I explained in my answer. Yes, there is a slightly shorter way using `\pgfplotsset`, please see the latest edit.

Comment: @koleygr [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235444/tikz-how-to-define-a-constant-and-then-use-it-in-drawing/235504#comment1277632_235504), is that what you expected?

Comment: @Diaa Maybe it's easier to understand this way: `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, foo=foovalue, bar=barvalue, baz}` is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{/tikz/foo=foovalue, /tikz/bar=barvalue, /tikz/baz}`. While we're at it, it's very useful to understand that when you do `\pgfkeys{/tikz/baz}`, the `/tikz/baz` key *is* passed a value. This eventually results in `/tikz/baz` using its *default* value (not to be confused with the key's *initial* value; look for example at the `tcolorbox` manual: the distinction between default and initial values is made very clear for each key).

Comment: Perfect @frougon ... More than what was expecting!