# pgfplots: How to iterate over plot styles using foreach?

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

For the following, the variable `\mystyle` doesn't work as expected.

Therefore, how can I:

1- optimize the code by making three lists of values of `\myalph`, `\mystyle`, and `\mylabel` to be iterated over by `foreach` instead of typing the combinations one-by-one,

2- then fix the code to make `\mystyle` work as a line style option?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{alph/.initial=1}
\newcommand*{\getalph}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/alph}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time) = \time^(\getalph-1); } ]
\begin{semilogxaxis}
\foreach \myalph/\mylabel/\mystyle in {0.1/{one}/dashed , 0.5/{two}/solid , 0.9/{three}/red}{
    \addplot[alph=\myalph, domain = 1e-6 : 1e6, samples = 100, \mystyle] {CFDfixedalph(x)};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{\mylabel}
}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are well-known pitfalls with `foreach` loops in pgfplots, which are well explained in section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the manual v1.16. This is why I am using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and some `\noexpand` trickery. Notice that this is not the unique way to make it work, but a possible way which is easily extendible to more loop variables. Then I believe you got "cheated" in the [answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505712/194703). Of course, not really cheated, because the answer is really great, right to the point and contains clear explanations. It is just that if I would want to solve the problem you have, I would just declare `CFDfixedalph` to be function of two variables, which it really is. Then you do not need any pgf keys trickery, just plug in the alpha value you like. Altogether the following works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function = { CFDfixedalph(\time,\alph) = \time^(\alph-1); } ]
\begin{semilogxaxis}
\edef\lstAlphs{0.1,0.5,0.9}
\edef\lstLabels{"one","two","three"}
\edef\lstStyles{"dashed","solid","red"}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myalph}{{\lstAlphs}[#1]} % <- CCB (carefully count braces)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mystyle}{{\lstStyles}[#1]} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylabel}{{\lstLabels}[#1]} 
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[domain = 1e-6 : 1e6, samples = 100,\mystyle]
    {CFDfixedalph(x,\myalph)};}
 \temp
 \addlegendentryexpanded{\mylabel}
}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I highly appreciate your effort to explain the main issue. However, I would be grateful to explain to me this rookie inquiry: what is the meaning of code line  `\edef\temp{\noexpand...`? and why did it end with `temp` before `\addlegendentryexpanded`?

Comment: @Diaa This makes sure that first the arguments of `\addplot` are expanded, and then the `\addplot` command. Note that pgfplots comes with `TeX-programming-notes.pdf`, where this is explained better than I could explain it.