# pgfplots: Exemplary comparison and differences between \foreach, \pgfplotsforeachungrouped, and \pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

[My previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505854/2288) made me take a look at [pgfplots manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#section.8.1) to understand the differences between `\foreach` and `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. However, the examples are not enough to comprehensively understand the differences and when to use each one.

Interestingly, I found the second variant of `foreach` (`\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`) whose examples are not verbosely explained nor enough.

Therefore, I would be grateful if there is an exemplary comparison between `\foreach` and its two variants to better understand them and wisely choose the appropriate one for my document.

Comment: The basic differences are that 1. `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` does not wrap the loop body in groups and 2. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` expands the loop "variable", whereas the other variant's do not. In case these statements do not make a lot of sense to you, you may want to look at ` TeX-programming-notes.pdf` that comes with `pgfplots` and `TeX by topic`, which is included in the standard TeX installations.