# Why don't the customized constants work in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{AnnArbor}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{wolverine} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,calc} 



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5,yscale=5]

\draw [<->] (0,1)--(0,0)--(1,0);


\def\constal{2/3};

\def\constax{\constal}

\def\constax{(1-\constal)^2}

\def\constA{\constx/(\constx+\consty)};

\def\constB{(\constal-\constx)/(1-\constx-\consty)};

\def\constC{(1-2*\constal+\constx)/(\constx+\consty)};

\def\constD{\constal^2/(\constal^2+(1-\constal)^2)};

\def\constE{1/2};

\def\constF{(1-\constal)^2/(\constal^2+(1-\constal)^2)};

\def\constG{(\constal^2+(1-\constal)^2)/2};

\def\constH{2*\constal*(1-\constal)};

\def\constI{(\constx+\consty)/2};

\def\constJ{1-\constx-\consty};

\node [below] at (1,0) {$\beta_1$};
\node [left] at (0,1) {$\beta_4$};

\draw ({(\constD-\constC)/(\constA-\constC)},{0})--({(\constD-\constC)/(\constA-\constC)},{1});

\draw[domain=0:1] plot (\x, {-\constG/\constH*\x+(\constA*\constI-\constF*\constG)/(\constA*\constH)});

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I defined several constants, but they cannot work in tikz. What is the mistake?

Comment: def is roughly speaking "text substitution", not "define constant". Try substituting the raw values inside the macros, you see it won't work either

Comment: Use pgf math set macro instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235504/250119

Comment: `\def` is a TeX primitive, so as a rule I suggest avoiding any use of such primitives in LaTeX code. If you want to define a new LaTeX macro, use `\newcommand`. If you want to define a PGF constant, use `\pgfmathsetmacro` as @user202729 suggested above.

Comment: It seems like you are not very familiar with the concept of this site, e. g. accepting answers, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour for a quick tour.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (instead of or in addition to `\pgfmathsetmacro`), is to use [Ti*k*Z `declare function`](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#pgf./pgf/declare:function). You then need some gimmick when you want to print the values (I use `siunitx` for this, it has a lot of formatting options).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\print}[2][round-mode=figures, round-precision=3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpval}{#2}%
    \num[#1]{\rpval}
}
\tikzset{declare function={
        a=2/3;
        b(\x)=(\x)^2 +1;
    }}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw[cyan] (0,0) grid (2,2);
    \draw ({a}, 0) -- ({b(a)}, 1); % {} are needed only in the second
                                   % coord, but better keep consinstency
    \node[below]{a=\print{a}, b=\print{b(a)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]