# Can I define a macro with same name as an already defined command?

Tags: macros

Somewhere in my document, I have a

```
\newcommand{\macomm}{blabla}
```

Later, I would like to define a TeX macro with the same name:

```
\def\macomm{blabla}
```

So my questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Will this make any problem?
3. Should/can I "kill" the definition of the command, before defining the TeX macro?

Comment: If you do `\def\macomm{...}` inside a group, when the group ends the previous definition will be restored.

Comment: `\def` overwrites an existing definition. No need to _kill_ it before.

Comment: TeX macros and LaTeX commands are the same thing, in that `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}` and `\def\foo{bar}` both create a macro called `\foo` with expansion `bar`. See [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes
2. The `\def` will overwrite without warning the previous meaning of `\macomm`. Only you can decide if this is a problem.
3. The `\def` already "kills" the previous definition.

The main question is why you want to use TeX-syntax in the second case. Why don't you use `\renewcommand\macomm{blub}`?