# \renewcommand for commands defined with \def

Tags: macros

In the following MWE I've used `\renewcommand` to redefine a command defined through `\def`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mymacro{Hello}
\renewcommand{\mymacro}{Hello world}

\begin{document}
\mymacro
\end{document}
```

and it works fine, as far as I can see.

What I would like to know is:

1. Are there cases in which it doesn't work?
2. Is it a good practice or I should I use `\def` to redefine commands defined through `\def`?

EDIT

I've already taken a look at [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand). What I mean is that sometimes I need to hack some commands defined through `\def` and I would like to know whether I'm allowed to do that with `\renewcommand` or not.

Comment: The general rule (in LaTeX) is not to use `\def` unless you need to. Use `\(re)newcommand` where possible.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the link. But see my edit.

Comment: `renewcommand` is only a wrapper around `\def`.

Comment: Short answers: (1) No; (2) Yes.

Comment: if a command created with `\def` is "context sensitive", it can't be redefined with `\renewcommand`.  but for a simple definition like the one you show, `\renewcommand` works just fine, and is probably preferable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you please extend your comment into an answer, showing a case in which it doesn't work? I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: All that `\renewcommand` requires is 1) that the command already have a meaning, 2) that it is not `\relax`, and 3) that it doesn't start with `\end`. It doesn't care how the command acquired it's meaning. It could be via `\def`, `\let` or even `\chardef`, `\countdef`, etc. What @barbarabeeton is saying is that `\renewcommand` can't always duplicate the argument syntax of the original command.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if a command created with `\def` is "context sensitive" (or "delimited"), it can't be redefined with `\renewcommand`. but for a simple definition like the one you show, `\renewcommand` works just fine, and is considered preferable in LaTeX.

the following pattern is used internally in `amsmath` to check the presence or class of symbols in order to "do the right thing" when defining symbol commands that are more flexible than similar ones provided by plain tex:

```
\def\@tempa#1#2\@nil{<...>}
```

the string `\@nil` looks like a command, but it really isn't.  instead, it is used as a "sentinel" to delimit the scope of what is being tested.

use of a sentinel in this matter avoids the need for braces when using the defined command.  the "LaTeX way" is to use braces, but in some contexts, the proliferation of braces makes input more difficult to read (and debug when errors occur), and the sentinel method can be used to advantage.

**edit:** as noted by @Dan, this doesn't mean that a command can't be redefined using `\renewcommand`, but that it's impossible to replicate the usage syntax of the original when doing so.