# How to define a macro to make a line of text red?

Tags: macros, comments

I'm looking for a way to make a new command that makes text on that and only that line red (or in another way clearly distinguishable).

Like the % symbol comments out a line. Are commands that work like that at all possible. I want to make short comments that print and I don't want to have to open and close braces each time.

Comment: If you are happy with ending the "line" to be captured by the macro with an empty line you can do `\def\bla#1\par{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`

Comment: I've always wondered how to do this. It's easy to define a command delimited by a `\par` or even a blank line directly (leaving a blank line after `#1` and the `{`). But it doesn't work if you want it to work just with that line (even if there is no blank line following). `\def\delimitedbyblankline#1

{Something with “#1”}`.

Comment: Related: [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for this purpose, it is easier to use a "delimited" argument, using `\def`.

rather than using `\par` as the delimiter (which will result in a paragraph break,
which may not always be wanted), you might choose a single non-`%` character that
won't appear in your comment text.  if `|` is such a character, this should work:

```
\def\bla#1|{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

this approach should work even if `\bla` doesn't begin a new line, and the whole
comment is embedded in a block of text.

(@Bordaigorl had the right idea in a comment, but `\par` may be too limiting.)

some additional commentary on this approach is given in the answer to this
question: [\renewcommand for commands defined with \def](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145357/579).

Comment: `\par` wouldn't make a paragraph break if it was being used as an argument delimiter, but why not use `\textcolor` directly rather than a delimited argument at all?

Answer (score 6):

The macro `\HighlightRestOfCurrentLine` below allows you to highlight to the end of the *current* line:

[image]

### References:

- Alternate methods of marking off portions of text are available at [Environments for visually setting text apart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart)

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing. Although I have a feeling this should be doable in just one run.
- The *magic* numbers for determing the edge of the page are obtained by using `\layout` from [the `layout` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/layouts).
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\HighlightRestOfCurrentLine}[1][]{%
    \tikzmark{Start}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (EdgeOfText) at ($(current page.west |- 0,0) + (1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,0.3ex) + (0.1em,1.6ex)$) ;
        \draw [draw=none,fill=green!50, #1]  ($(Start)+(0,-0.6ex)$) rectangle (EdgeOfText);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}%\layout
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dignissim eros. 
 Morbi faucibus sit amet felis a accumsan. \HighlightRestOfCurrentLine Aliquam 
 dapibus pellentesque dui, vitae aliquam turpis semper eget. 
 Donec egestas leo nibh, at malesuada leo congue non. 
 Cras laoreet lectus sed tortor laoreet, ac aliquet nibh condimentum. 
 Nam elementum ante non nunc facilisis porttitor. Nullam non suscipit lorem. 
 Sed arcu dui, accumsan et pretium dictum, venenatis id metus.

Mauris massa lacus, vehicula 
vitae \HighlightRestOfCurrentLine[fill=none,draw=gray, ultra thick] blandit ac, 
fermentum vitae ligula. Maecenas ultricies, tortor a sodales ullamcorper, 
erat lorem semper leo, vel pretium felis arcu ut velit. Aenean viverra 
lacus at nisi malesuada luctus. Maecenas libero odio, luctus et blandit 
vitae, commodo in turpis. Duis nisi enim, gravida id libero id, 
sollicitudin volutpat purus. Curabitur rhoncus risus euismod arcu venenatis, 
\HighlightRestOfCurrentLine[red!25]non elementum mi lobortis. 
Pellentesque quis leo eu nunc malesuada condimentum. Ut dictum iaculis 
aliquam. Nunc tincidunt a ligula in adipiscing. Praesent 
\HighlightRestOfCurrentLine[fill=none,draw=blue, dotted, ultra thick]ultricies sem 
odio, eget pellentesque mi faucibus vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu 
ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Sed ullamcorper massa risus, non commodo dolor eleifend quis. 
Mauris ultrices lorem a orci hendrerit tempor. Sed fringilla mattis fringilla. 
\end{document}
```