# Changing from \def to \newcommand*

Tags: macros

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\door(#1,#2)#3{
  \psline[
    linecap = 0,
    linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = white
  ](#1,#2)(!#1 #2 #3 add)
  \psline[
    linecap = 2
  ](#1,#2)(!#1 #3 add #2)
  \psarc[
    linestyle = dotted
  ](#1,#2){#3}{0}{90}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
  \door(0,0){1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change `\def` to `\newcommand*` and keep the syntax

```
\door(a,b){c}
```

instead of

```
\door{0}{0}{1}
```

?

Comment: Be careful with unnecessary whitespaces in your macro body as `\rput` will not remove them.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Yes. This is one thing I have a problem with; to be honest, I have no idea when there will be whitespaces in my macros and when not. (I can of course end every line with `%` but this is a very tiresome task.)

Comment: Missing out `%` at the end of a line does have a useful function of helping egreg keep ahead of us all as he earns most of his rep points by telling people to put `%` at ends of lines.

Comment: Why do you want to change to `\newcommand*` ?

Comment: @lhf Because of [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand).

Comment: But for your use, the pattern matching of `\def` seems ideal.

Comment: \newcommand was intended to be less confusing  than \def (DDP).  Consequently, it is also less useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\def` allows for specifying the parameter text that is to be expected, while `\newcommand` does not. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) brings this back, but not with the simplicity that accompanies `\def`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,xparse}
\def\door(#1,#2)#3{
  \psline[
    linecap = 0,
    linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = white
  ](#1,#2)(!#1 #2 #3 add)
  \psline[
    linecap = 2
  ](#1,#2)(!#1 #3 add #2)
  \psarc[
    linestyle = dotted
  ](#1,#2){#3}{0}{90}
}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Xdoor}{ > { \SplitArgument {1} {,} } r() m}{% 
  \psline[
    linecap = 0,
    linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = white
  ](\@firstoftwo#1,\@secondoftwo#1)(!\@firstoftwo#1 \@secondoftwo#1 #2 add)
  \psline[
    linecap = 2
  ](\@firstoftwo#1,\@secondoftwo#1)(!\@firstoftwo#1 #2 add \@secondoftwo#1)
  \psarc[
    linestyle = dotted
  ](\@firstoftwo#1,\@secondoftwo#1){#2}{0}{90}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(3,1)
  \door(0,0){1}
  \Xdoor(2,0){1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

`\SplitArgument{1}{,}` splits `r()` - a `r`equired argument that is delimited by `(`...`)` - into two parts that should be separated by `,` in the following way: `(a,b)` > `{a}{b}`. As such, `\@firstoftwo#1` results in `a`, and `\@secondoftwo#1` results in `b`. Of course, you could define commands for these rather than `\@first`-/`\@secondoftwo`.

Comment: I'll just stick to `\def` but thanks for the nice answer.