# Iteratively define Header/Footer

Tags: header-footer

I wrote a LaTeX document (approx. 50 pages) with 2 classmates together. Now i want to show who wrote which part in at the top right of each page.
For example at page 2-15 will be my name at the top right corner and at the top right corner is something like "calendar week 30".

How can I do something like that?

Comment: Related http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\def \thekw {0}
\def \thespecificauthor {My Name}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\rhead{KW \thekw~- \thespecificauthor}
```

When I modify these variables via

```
\def \thekw {21}
```

in the document, the following headers will be correct.

Comment: I would actually prefer `\newcommand*` and `\renewcommand*`.

Comment: Why do you prefer it? Would it work, too?

Comment: See [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655). May also be interesting: [Why are some LaTeX macros defined using \newcommand and some using \def?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150137).