# \newcommand vs \def for class development

Tags: macros, def

By reading the contents of the file `book.cls` (the standard book class for LaTeX), I can see there are many uses of `\def` and `\newcommand`. What I don't seem to understand is why one is used in some cases and why the other in other cases. I couldn't find a pattern.

I understand the differences between`\def` and `\newcommand`, and I am aware that I should prefer the latter in everyday document writing. However, my question goes on the context of class and package development. For example, I could define a `\title` command for my new book class, that also accepts a subtitle as optional argument, by writing

```
\def\doc@title{}
\def\doc@subtitle{}
\def\title{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\@@title}{\@title}%
\def\@title#1{
    \@@title[]{#1}%
}
\def\@@title[#1]#2{%
    \gdef\doc@subtitle{#1}
    \gdef\doc@title{#2}
}
```

However, I could also say

```
\newcommand\doc@title{}
\newcommand\doc@subtitle{}
\newcommand{\title}[2][]{
    \gdef\doc@subtitle{#1}
    \gdef\doc@title{#2}
}
```

**Is there any reason to prefer one way over the other in the previous pieces of code?**

Similarly, the `book.cls` file has this line:

```
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
```

**Why is it not written as**

```
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\@ptsize{0}}
```

**In class/package development, what are the criteria to use `\newcommand` in some situation and `\def` in other?**

Comment: Related question, but not quite the answer I was looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150137/why-are-some-latex-macros-defined-using-newcommand-and-some-using-def

Comment: what answer are you looking for that is not a duplicate of that?

Comment: "Sadly the answers in the linked questions is the truth, regardless whether you like it or not." ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expl3, and all the `\XX_new:N` command families and their nuances enter the picture too. :)

[image: expl3]

Expl3 is *much* easier to code in.

Same (philosophical) answer at base as the linked question, though.

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_ds_doctitle_tl
\tl_new:N \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl
\tex_def:D \mymeta #1 {
    \textsf{\textbf{ #1 }}
}
\tex_def:D \commandbuild #1#2#3 {
        \c_backslash_str
        #1
        \c_underscore_str
        #2
        \c_colon_str
        #3
}
\tex_def:D \texdef {
        \begin{center}
        The ~ difference ~ between ~ X ~ and ~ Y
        \end{center}
        \begin{center}
        \mymeta { \commandbuild {tex}{def}{D} } ~ and ~ all ~ the ~
        \mymeta { \commandbuild {XX}{new}{N} } ~ commands
        \end{center}
        }


\NewDocumentCommand { \mytitle } { o +m } {
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_ds_doctitle_tl { #2 }
    \IfValueT { #1 }
    {
            \tl_gset:Nx \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl { #1 }

            \regex_replace_all:nnN
                    { (subtitle)+ }
                    { \c{underline} \cB\{ \0 \cE\} }
                    \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl

            \tl_gput_left:Nn \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl 
            { 
                    \vspace { 2\tex_baselineskip:D }
                    \begin{center}
            }
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl 
            { 
                    \end{center}
            }
                    
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_ds_doctitle_tl 
            { 
                    \large \upshape 
            }
            \tl_gput_right:NV \g_ds_doctitle_tl \g_ds_docsubtitle_tl
    }
    
    \tl_gput_left:Nn \g_ds_doctitle_tl { \Large }
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_ds_doctitle_tl { \texdef }
            
}



\NewDocumentCommand { \printtitle } { } {
        \tl_if_empty:NF \g_ds_doctitle_tl
        {
        \group_begin:
        \center
        \itshape
        \tl_use:N \g_ds_doctitle_tl
        \group_end:
        }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\mytitle[My subtitle A]{Multiparagraph

My Title A}

%============  document 
\begin{document}
\printtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Computer scientists keep telling me that new languages are easier to use.  I guess it's true if you think more like a computer sicentist an less like a computer.  I find assembly language easier to use.

Comment: Expl3 is much easier to code in, but only in the sense that web pages with pop-up ads are much easier to read.