# tweaking a resume template to allow custom bibtex categories

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

So I use LaTeX a lot for work. I'm in the process of creating a new academic CV.

I found a [beautiful](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) template that I really love, but handles bibtex references in an unweildy manner. It assumes something is a conference piece or a journal article by the type of bibtex entry.  (@misc, @inproceedings, @article, etc)

This is problematic since for example, I have workshops I've attended that published proceedings and were counted as "peer reviewed". Sometimes they were not peer reviewed, but these would be lumped together with the first CV's approach. Another issue is the whole @misc section is a jumble of posters, invited talks, and links to news articles about me.

My [old cv template](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cv/) isn't very pretty, but it handles bibtex citations in a much more usable manner.

Basically, it lets you predeclare your categories and list the cites that go in each. (Example below)

```
\bibliography{pubs}
\addtocategory{books}{MWH3,ITSM91,ITSM94,expsmooth08}
\addtocategory{papers}{BHG91,BH92,YW93,Hyndman94,HDRF95}
\addtocategory{papers}{HDR96,HBG96,HF96,GHH97,HW97,LFSH97,GH98}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use the citation method from my old CV, but with the visual look from the new one.

I've attempted merging the new resumé's .cls and the old resumé's .sty, but I know very little about making templates and just get a mass of errors. It seemed like a simple matter of replacing one template's references code with the other, but I can't get it to compile.

Is there any way I can force the new CV style I found to let me have my own custom groupings?

I tried pulling the citation code from one templatr and puttin it in the other, but it just leads to a mass of errors, and no matter how much I google I can't get it to compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome Greggarious. It would help if you provided a minimal working example illustrating what it is that's not working as expected. Also, are you aware that the template you'd like to use is based on `biblatex`? You might want to check out the documentation of this package, it handles a few things differently to `bibtex`, but ultimately is much more powerful.

Comment: Thanks,

It's kind of hard to do a traditional minimum working example since I can't get it to compile... 

I've got the source code I used for the .sty [here](http://pastebin.com/i4BGr6X0).

And [here](http://pastebin.com/5xw6HexQ) is a link to a stripped down example CV.

I googled for documentation, and it looks like my .bib file should work with both...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realized now that your old cv also uses `biblatex`, my bad. I'll see if I can do anything to help in the next couple of days, but this could well be out of my reach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a modified version of `friggeri-cv.cls`. Open the file, go to the Bibliography part and add the option `backend=biber` to the `biblatex` package option.
Then, comment out the part where the command `\printbibsection` is being defined. Below the sorting scheme definition add

```
\newcommand*{\makebibcategory}[2]{\DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}\defbibheading{#1}[#2]{\subsection*{#2}}}
\makebibcategory{books}{Books}
\makebibcategory{papers}{Refereed research papers}
\makebibcategory{chapters}{Book chapters}
\makebibcategory{conferences}{Papers in conference proceedings}
\makebibcategory{techreports}{Unpublished working papers}
\makebibcategory{bookreviews}{Book reviews}
\makebibcategory{editorials}{Editorials}
\makebibcategory{phd}{PhD thesis}
\makebibcategory{subpapers}{Submitted papers}
\makebibcategory{curpapers}{Current projects}

\newcommand*{\printbib}[1]{\printbibliography[sorting=chronological,category=#1,heading=#1]}
```

By the way, I changed the `\def`s to `\newcommands`, because of this [tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand).

Then, in the preamble of your actual CV file (I again based it on Friggeri's template), just add the command `\addbibresource{example.bib}` to add your `.bib` file (this command replaces the `\bibliography` command in recent versions of `biblatex`).

Under the section **Publications**, take out everything and add

```
\nocite{*}
\addtocategory{books}{Griebel.etal-Numericalsimulationin1998}
\addtocategory{papers}{Akervik.etal-Globaltwo-dimensionalstability2008}
\addtocategory{chapters}{Grisvard-Ellipticproblemsin1985}
\addtocategory{conferences}{Rham.Albone-EvolutionaryFarField1196}
\addtocategory{techreports}{Abdulrahim.Cocquyt-Developmentofmission-capable2000,Adoua.etal-Reversaloflift2009}
\addtocategory{bookreviews}{Skalak.Kucera-notecouplingof2004}
\addtocategory{editorials}{Sverak-LandausSolutionsNavier2011}
\addtocategory{phd}{Grote-Nonreflectingboundaryconditions1995}
\addtocategory{subpapers}{Sohr-specialclassof1999}
\addtocategory{curpapers}{BVPswithsingularitiesinphasevariables}

\printbib{books}
\printbib{papers}
\printbib{chapters}
\printbib{conferences}
\printbib{techreports}
\printbib{bookreviews}
\printbib{editorials}
```

Of course, you'll want to adapt your keys to what makes sense in your case. This patchwork of Friggeri's and your own propositions seems to work decently over on my side. Tell me how it works.

Comment: Hi,

This seems to work, but when running biber I am told 

`Cannot find control file '(lastname).tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`

That's a bit confusing since my .cls has been updated to do that, here's the revelant snippet: `\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt, backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: Realized I should have been running `biber cvsources' (since bib file is cvsources.bib. But I still get the same error `biber ./cvsources
INFO - This is Biber 1.6
INFO - Logfile is './cvsources.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file './cvsources.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1'

Comment: Hmm, I never encountered that error. I guess you tried to delete everything but the .bib and the .tex? I'm running `biber 1.8`, `biblatex 2.8a` and `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013103115 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`.

Comment: Yeah... to clarify, you would run xelatex (filename); biber (filename); then run xelatex again twice, right? Maybe I'm just giving the wrong file name to biber - should it be the name of the .tex or the .bib? Should I leave on the file extension?

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it. I've got a file `test.tex` and my sources are in `ref.bib`, which is referenced in the .tex file by the `\addbibresource` command. Then I run `xelatex test.tex`, followed by `biber test` (no extension, and certainly not `biber ref`!), and `xelatex test.tex` again. Does that work?

Comment: No it doesn't... crap. I should be writing \addbibresource{cvsources.bib} right? I tried with and without the .bib and still get the [same error](http://pastebin.com/4stwwQf9)

Do you think you could post your test files on pastebin? I'm really lost why this is not compiling. I have the name of the .bib in there. I double checked it's spelled correctly and in the proper location, so I'm not sure why it's claiming it's empty. I can use a .bib file w/ biber right?

Comment: Sure, `biber` reads .bib files, and your use of the `\addbibresource` command seems fine. Here are the modified [.tex](http://pastebin.com/CGD6DwvE) and the modified [.cls](http://pastebin.com/RvNbM1jM). Try to update your `biber` and `biblatex` versions if it still doesn't work, although I doubt that's the reason.

Comment: I found the issue... I forgot to add in the \nocite, which caused biber to give that error. Thanks a ton!