# Vertical bar turning horizontal

Tags: arrays

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,multicol}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blocks}[9][-10]{
    \def\bar{\@ifstar{\raisebox{-5pt}{\scb{1}[1]{\Huge{|}}}\hsp{0.2cm}}{\raisebox{-14pt}{\scb{1}[1.3]{\Huge{|}}}\hsp{0.2cm}}}

    \!\!\mat{cccc}
        #2&#3\hsp{-0.2cm}&\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\bar\raisebox{#1pt}{\Huge{$#6$}}}}\\
        #4&#5\hsp{-0.2cm}\\[0.2em]\hline\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{#9pt}{\Huge{$#7$}\hsp{-0.2cm}}}}&\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\bar*\raisebox{#9pt}{\Huge{$#8$}}}}\\
        \\
        \emat\!\!}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mat}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\emat}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\scb}{\scalebox}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace}

\begin{document}
$$\blocks{\cosh u}{\sinh u}{\sinh u}{\cosh u}{0}{0}{1}.$$
\end{document}
```

Typesetting it generates what I expect, except that the | appear as horizontal bars. Why? And why does changing them to `$|$` turn them vertical?

Comment: First of all make a compilable example, I get several errors.

Comment: Do you know [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the ascii `|` has the internal code `"7C`.

in computer modern text fonts, position `"7C` is occupied by the em-dash.

when you pack something into a box (`\raisebox` here), it reverts to horizontal mode,
hence `|` accesses the em-dash.

as you have discovered, `$|$` accesses the vertical bar, because in the math font,
the ascii position is used for this symbol.

by pure blind luck, you have hit on a combination that looks like all that it changes
is the orientation of the shape.  if you want the bar to be vertical, remember that it
has to be in math mode if it's in a box.

Answer (score 5):

It's really a bad idea to redefine `\bar`. Plus you're doing by hand things that are already available, using characters that are not what you're expecting: typing `|` in text mode is not really a good idea, unless you're loading the T1 encoding.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\newcommand{\blocks}[7]{%
  \begin{array}{c|c}
  \begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
  #1 & #2 \\
  #3 & #4
  \end{array} &
  \xbox[-0.8ex]{#5} \\[2ex]
  \hline
  & \\[-1.5ex]
  \xbox{#6} &
  \xbox{#7}
  \end{array}%
}
\newcommand\xbox[2][0pt]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\raisebox{#1}{\Huge\ $#2$\ }\end{tabular}% 
}

\begin{document}
\[
\blocks{\cosh u}{\sinh u}{\sinh u}{\cosh u}{0}{0}{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By "redefine" do you mean `\bar` already has a definition or do you just mean I shouldn't redefine it every time I call `\blocks`?

Comment: @MickG It has a definition, the “bar” math accent, so it's not wise to redefine it. For the general problem, one redefines something if its definition should depend on current conditions.

Comment: I see. I didn't know. I will fix this. Thanks for telling me :).

Comment: PS it should be `\newcommand{\xbox}` with braces around `\xbox`, shouldn't it? And the tabular around the `\raisebox` in `\xbox`? What is it for?

Comment: `\newcommand{\xbox}` and `\newcommand\xbox` are equivalent. The tabular is for vertical centering and for using `\Huge` inside it.

Comment: Uh-huh. What if I want `\hline` and `|` in the 2x2 submatrix? How do I get the `\hline` to extend to the border of the column? And why do you say the tabular is «for using `\Huge` inside it»?

Comment: @MickG I can't follow you. You seem to favor complications.

Comment: Never mind, I've solved that myself. Just have to fiddle with the padding spaces. But in what sense do you need a tabular to use `\Huge` in it?

Comment: @MickG Just because it's easier: in an `array` I would have to use \mbox{\Huge$0$}`, while in a `tabular` cells are in text mode.

Comment: But then @egreg since it is in a `\raisebox` the `\mbox` shouldn't be needed, right? I mean, my example (except for the `\par` being generated by the double line feed) works, and there is no tabular.

Answer (score 4):

The example shows many issues, some of them:

- [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/16967)
- [What is the difference between `\def` and `\newcommand`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/16967)
  `\bar` is overwritten by `\blocks`.
- `\Huge` and friends do not have an argument. The effect of the font size command remains active until the current group ends: `{\Huge #1}` instead of `\Huge{#1}`.
- Code formatting, code formatting, code formatting.
- ...

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\blocks}[7]{%
  \begingroup
    \newcommand*{\hugemath}[1]{\mbox{\Huge$##1$}}%
    \begin{tabular}{r|l}
      $%
        % @{} removes space at the left and right, because
        % the surrounding tabular adds already space.
        \begin{array}[b]{@{}cc@{}}
          #1&#2\\
          #3&#4%
        \end{array}
      $%
      & \mbox{\Huge$#5$}\\
      \hline
      % the following trick adds vertical space above
      % the contents of the row with the amount of the depth
      % of a table line. Then the `\hline` is in the middle.
      % \@finalstrut\@arstrutbox is the depth of a tabular
      % line (e.g. this is added at the end of a line in
      % a cell of column type "p".
      \settodepth{\dimen@}{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox}%
      \raisebox{\dimen@}{%
        \vphantom{\hugemath#6#7}%
      }%
      \hugemath{#6}
      & \hugemath{#7}%
    \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \blocks{\cosh u}{\sinh u}{\sinh u}{\cosh u}{0}{0}{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

The default OT1  encoding has ligatures (emdash here) and other things in the ascii punctuation slots, try

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

OT1 is strange < | >

\end{document}
```