# Characters with unexpected glyphs in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, rendering

I just ran into the fact that the ASCII vertical bar character is (unexpectedly and inexplicably) rendered as a long dash in LaTeX. So presumably there could be other such characters that aren’t “special” (in the sense of being non-text “control“ characters when unescaped) yet are rendered by `LaTeX` in a totally non-standard way

Is there a specification somewhere that lists these “non-standard rendering” characters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Let me guess: the "vertical bar character" is being rendered in text mode, not math mode, right? (Other such characters are `>` and `<`.) To fix this issue, run the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble. BTW, *nothing* in LaTeX is "inexplicable". The explanation can be challenging at times, though...

Comment: You should read about the [different font encodings in TeX](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf), how glyphs in fonts are mapped using TeX and also about the differences of the different TeX engines (PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX). If you use PDFLaTeX, `|` is parsed as codepoint `7C` which results in an em-dash for the traditional Computer Modern text fonts (but maybe not for other fonts). See as well [Q193216](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193216/) .

Comment: the default (old) encoding OT1 allows only 128 glyphs per fonts, and to squeeze all needed glyphs into the fonts the fonts have a number of oddities. The best is to use either an unicode engine (lualatex) or to switch to a larger encoding with  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`