# Diagram reuse across Beamer slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In my dissertation defense presentation (Beamer/TikZ), I have a particular slide with a model, built as `tikzpicture`, wrapped in a `scalebox` block for zoom control. It works fine.

However, I would like to **reuse** this diagram's code in another slide further in the presentation to display a *smaller* version of the same model (along with a text block) for reference, in order to avoid the need to navigate multiple slides backward and forward again. This is quite important, because: 1) I plan to use a presenter device (remote), which makes such transitions not feasible; 2) I don't want to abruptly switch the context and disrupt the flow of my presentation.

Ideally, I would like to define the model as LaTeX variable and refer to it in both places with different zoom levels, using `scalebox`. Is such reuse possible and, if yes, how could I do that?

Comment: Put the whole `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` in `mytikzfigure.tex` and then use `\input{mytikzfigure}`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @yo': Thank you, but I prefer to have a single `.tex` file, if possible.

Comment: \def\model{\begin{tikz....\end{tikzpicture}}and than just \model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer putting the code in another file `mytikzfigure.tex` -- including `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` -- and using `\input{mytikzfigure}`.

If you want it in one file, then:

```
\newcommand\myTikZfigure{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Hello};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

and then `\scalebox{0.5}{\myTikZfigure}`.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Thank you so much! Is there any particular reason for preferring placing code block in a separate file (considering that this is not a frequent matter throughout my presentation; I realize that, generally, it's a best practice for _modularity_)? Also, what is the difference between `\newcommand` you suggested and `\def`, suggested by touhami?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Yes. Cleanliness. Currently, my slides have ~20 lines of code each, so it's easy to navigate the source. However, a TikZ figure can easily have hundreds of lines of code, whence I prefer it to be separate. I do that also for papers, needed to say.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand i can say that \newcommand is better.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh You can remove your comments that are not adding anything. It's actually encouraged to do so.