# Is it permitted to have arguments (i.e. value in key-value) including \par in the xkeyval package?

Tags: paragraphs, xkeyval

I wish to use the `xkeyval` package to overide the 9 arguments limit and to clarifiy the different arguments (compulsory or optional).
In my arguments/parameters, I have complete paragraphs possibly including `\par` or `\\\\`.
I know that some macros accepts `\par`, others don't, to avoid hidden problematic nestings I understand. It seems that the prefix `\long` allows to have `\par` within arguments. In the implementation part of the doc, I see plenty of these `\long` macros.

Does that guarantee I can use `\par` in the arguments/value within the package `xkeyval`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try it? ;-)

Comment: Yes it should work. Alternatively, if you are using aTeX and use `\newcommand` instead `\def` to define macros then this is automatic. Other differences are discussed in [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am trying ! But, since I don't know how to use xkeyval,  if one says "no way, it won't work" I would try something else :)

Comment: @user1771398: Well, it works, as shown in my answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the pedagogic document that allow to see what works and what doesn't ! Now I feel I understand the 'xkeyval' and application to text with '\par', '\\' etc.
Together with Andrew, I also better understand the nature of '\newcommand' and '\newcommand*'

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\newline` or `\\` after an empty line would be an error anyway, but otherwise it's ok (if really necessary ;-)). `\par` or empty lines will do in a key as well.

Just mustn't define the command `\foocmd` as `\newcommand*{}` but as `\newcommand`.

If you want to be on the safe side, use `\NewDocumentCommand{\foocmd}{+o+m}{...}` from the `xparse` package, the `+` character allows explicitly `\par` etc. in the argument then.

---

Some background

TeX's `\def` command does not allow arguments with a parbreak etc, unless the `\def` usage is preceeded with `\long` (see the example below).

LaTeX's `\newcommand` is basically a wrapper for `\long\def...`, so it does allow `\par`, empty lines and `\newline` and `\\`, whereas `\newcommand*` is the 'un`\long`' version of it, disallowing this features.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter

\define@key{foofamily}{foo}{%
  \def\KVfookey{#1}%
}




\def\foodef[#1]#2{%
\setkeys{foofamily}{#1}%

\ifdefined\KVfookey
  The key had the value \KVfookey
\fi

Mandatory argument was #2
}

\long\def\foodeflong[#1]#2{%
\setkeys{foofamily}{#1}%

\ifdefined\KVfookey
  The key had the value \KVfookey
\fi

Mandatory argument was #2
}


\makeatother


\newcommand*{\fooother}[2][foo={A long

key
}]{%
\setkeys{foofamily}{#1}%
Arg was #2%
}

\newcommand{\foocmd}[2][foo={A long

Arg 

}]{%
\setkeys{foofamily}{#1}%
The key was \KVfookey

And this is the 2nd argument: #2%
}

\begin{document}

% Won't work, since arg isn't long
%\foodef[foo={Some 

%key}]{Hello World again}

% Won't work, since defined with `\newcommand*` .. i.e not \long\def...
%\fooother{Hello World}

\begin{itemize}
\item Using a \verb+\long\def+ command -- works
\foodeflong[foo={Some 

key}]{Hello World again}

\item Using a \verb+\newcommand+ command -- works

\foocmd{Hello World}

\foocmd[foo={A very long command  \newline\newline


\par
\parskip=5cm

key}]{... which is absolutely useless}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]