# Why I can not define commands starting with \end?

Tags: macros

I am trying to define some new commands starting with the word end and I found that it is impossible in TeX. For example,  the following code does not work. My question is: Is it possible to define new commands starting with \end... in (La)TeX?

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\endofproof}{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Clear. \hfill  \endofproof
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to inform that there is the command qedhere

Comment: There's no need to add an `\endofproof` command: if you prefer a black tombstone, redefine `\qedsymbol`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62266/4427 for reference about the problem in the title

Comment: My question is general. I know that on could redefine qed. But there are some situations that I need to define a command starting with end. For example there are some musicalterms in my language that are  starting with end so when I am trying to define  some musical symbols like repetions: endhere, startfromhere I need commands starting with the words end or start .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by `\def`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\def\endofproof{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Clear. \hfill  \endofproof
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The result IS strange. You probably simply want to redefine `\qedsymbol`.

Comment: Scherwentk  Oh! I forget \def command. So \newcommand has many restrictions indeed! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @kornaros Well, it only tells you if you're doing something you shouldn't be doing ... `\def` happily overwrites any existing macro without checking anything (I think).

Comment: @kornaros it is not that `\newcommand` has restrictions, it is what defines the latex language. If you use `\def` to undercut the language in this way things will break in surprising ways.