# Why can I not define commands beginning with "\end" with \newcommand?

Tags: macros

Note: I have seen a seemingly duplicate question at [Why I can not define commands starting with \end?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272213/why-i-can-not-define-commands-starting-with-end) that offers a workaround but does not really answer the "Why" part of the question. This question is meant to really understand the "Why" part.

Example code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\endnote}{endnote}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: Command \endnote already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \newcommand{\endnote}{endnote}
                                  
?
```

The error messages asks me to read page 192 of manual. But I could not understand which manual it is referring to. I would like to know exactly why LaTeX refuses to create a command that begins with `\end`.

Comment: It seems to be a protection built in by `\newcommand`, since all environments create a macro `\end<environmentname>`, your definition, if executed, would overwrite a hypothetical environment named `note`.  You can `\def\endnote{}`, but you do so at your own risk.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes +1 from me. Btw: In the context of macros `\<environmentname>` and  `\<endenvironmentname>` underlying environments I especially like the environments `csname` and `group`. ;-))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an `\newenvironment` is defined, two macros are created.  As an example, consider an environment named `note`.  The two created macros are `\note` and `\endnote`.  Thus, any environment created will have a macro associated with it that begins with `\end...`.  Novice users may not realize that the creation of an environment named `note` ties up a macro named `\endnote`.

This answer may explain the dangers of allowing `\end...` as a macro name.  If issued after the creation of a corresponding environment, it ruins the environment.  If issued before the creation of a corresponding environment, the macro gets overwritten.

Thus, my speculation is that `\newcommand` expressedly forbids it, to avoid this confusion since, to the novice, there may not seem any connection between a macro named `\endnote` and an environment named `note`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{note}{Note:}{The End}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}
Hi mom
\end{note}

\def\endnote{endnote}
\endnote

\begin{note}
Hi mom
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Often environments are defined by means of the `\newenvironment`-macro whereby the underlying macros `\⁠⟨environmentname⟩` and `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩` are defined**.

If an environment is defined this way, then the `\begin`-macro beneath other things opens up a new scope/group and within that scope/group calls the macro `\⁠⟨environmentname⟩` via `\csname ⁠⟨environmentname⟩⁠\endcsname`.

If an environment is defined this way, then the `\end`-macro beneath other things calls the macro `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩` via `\csname end⁠⟨environmentname⟩⁠\endcsname` and afterwards closes the scope/group opened up by the `\begin`-macro.

`\csname ⁠⟨macroname⟩\endcsname` delivers the token `\⁠⟨macroname⟩`. **In case the token delivered is not already defined at the time of delivery by `\csname..\endcsname`, it will be defined equal to the `\relax`-primitive within the current scope/group. (The `\relax`-primitive is a non-expandable no-op which makes it into TeX's stomach.)**

A token being undefined or being defined equal to the `\relax`-primitive is the same for `\newcommand`: If you do `\let\foobar=\relax`, then you can afterwards perfectly do `\newcommand{\foobar}...` without getting an error about `\foobar` being already defined. Actually `\newcommand` doesn't check if the command to be defined is undefined. `\newcommand` actually checks if it is the case that the command to define either is undefined or equals `\relax`. If this is the case, the definition will be performed. If this is not the case, i.e., if the command to define is defined different to `\relax`, then an error-message about the command in question being already defined is raised.

**If a macro `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩` was defined for every environment, then `\newcommand` forbidding the defining of macros with the phrase "\end" in their name would not be necessary.** Checking for (underlying) macros already being defined different from `\relax` would be sufficient both with `\newcommand` and with `\newenvironment`.

The `\newenvironment`-macro is a nice tool for defining environments but actually the `\begin`-macro and the `\end`-macro "don't care" how the defining of underlying macros `\⁠⟨environmentname⟩` and `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩` was done.

**Sometimes** environments are defined not by using `\newenvironment` but by just defining the underlying `\⁠⟨environmentname⟩`-macro directly while **leaving the `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩`-macro undefined**, relying on the circumstance that invocation as `\csname end⟨environmentname⟩⁠\endcsname` via the `\end`-macro would yield the `\relax`-no-op  as within the scope/group of the current environment the macro `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩` is undefined.

**Thus forbidding the defining of macros with `\end...` in their name prevents accidentally/erroneously defining an `\end⁠⟨environmentname⟩`-macro for an environment where none should be defined.**

Comment: Do you have an example of a environment that does not define its own `\end<environment>` ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\begin{small} ... \end{small}` :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  E.g., the environment `comment` of the package "comment". :-)  (Defining macros `\environmentname` but not defining macros `\endenvironmentname` is a common thing with environments that process things under verbatim-catcode-régime until encountering a sequence of character-tokens `e`, `n`, `d`, `{`, ..., `}`.)  Besides this it is perfectly legal to use, e.g.,  font-changing-commands like `\large` as environments `\begin{large}`...`\end{large}` although `\endlarge` is undefined.

Comment: Fasinating...so it is just a glorified scoping mechanism for an existing declarative (i.e., argument-free) macro.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes There comes some useful infrastructure with that scoping mechanism. E.g., error-messages. E.g., macros/switches for vertical spacing before and after the environment, paragraph-breaking after the environment, an environment-specific variant of `\@esphack` etc. ;-)  Besides this - if the environment is to process arguments, then the underlying `\<environmentname>`-macro is not necessarily argument-free. ;-)