# Can you use two types of delimiters in \def?

Tags: macros

In this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand), it was mentioned that any character can be used as a delimiter using `def`. Is it possible to define a function with two types of delimiters?

In particular I'm looking to define an analogue to `\alert` in beamer but which hides text instead of displays it. My naive guess would be:

```
\def\hide<#1> {#2}{\color<#1>{\usebeamercolor{hidden text}} #2}
```

where `hidden text` is a predefined beamercolor of a hard-to-see color. The first argument is given by angle brackets and the second by braces. However, upon compiling this results in the error:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \hide

**EDIT:** My original version had the wrong syntax. I should have written,

```
\def\hide<#1> {#2}{\color<#1>{black}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hidden text}{#2}}}
```

where the color black is a harmless place-holder which is overwritten by `\usebeamercolor`

Comment: Have you tried removing the curly braces around `#2`?

Comment: Do you know you can do `\newcommand<>{\hide}[1]{{\color#2{\usebeamercolor{hidden text}}#1}}`?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I didn't know. I thought that only `\def` can use non-brace deliminators

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\def\hide<#1> {#2}
```

would define a macro with one parameter delimited by `<` and `>space` but the replacement text uses `#2` hence the error.

You do not mark `{}` for "normal" arguments so

```
\def\hide<#1>#2{\color<#1>{black}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hidden text}{#2}}}
```

note no space after `>` and no `{}`

Comment: one *could* put a space after `>` but then it would be required.  you should add an example of use.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sure, if the original question had had an example I'd have updated it but since it didn't I didn't. I'm not sure `\color<x>{\usebeamercolor` is correct (looks a bit odd but perhaps that's Ok in beamer) But in any case that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Just a comment in case anyone actually uses this for beamer purpose. I screwed up the syntax for 'color' in the question. This version seems to work though "\def\hide<#1>#2{\color<#1>{black}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hidden text}{#2}}}", where the black is just there because you need a placeholder for color.

Comment: @JeffDror you could fix the color syntax in your question, and i'll do same here, will be less confusing in the archives that way.