# Create custom template

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am trying to create my own report template. The idea is that users have only to enter variables and focus on the contents. I tried to create an altered titlepage but get an error, my testreport.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testreport}[2017/04/02 v0.1 test report template]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% for the title page
\newcommand*{\client}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand*{\project}[1]{{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
\title
\\
\project
\\
\client
\\
\date
\\
\author

\end{titlepage}
}
```

And I have the following in my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{testreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Custom class example}
\author{Yorian}
\date{\today}
\project{aa}
\client{BB}

\begin{document}

% Create title page
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

But I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21 \maketitle

?
```

I don't see what's going wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: `\title`, `\author`, and `\date`, as well as `\project` and `\client`, are all commands that take arguments. This doesn't seem to be the case in the template file, though.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- macros like `\title{Custom class example}` are there to input information. If you want to retrieve this information again, you need to call another macro in which the information is stored. For title this would be `\@title`, but you can create this also for your own fields.
- don't misuse `\\`, see [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines)

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \makeatletter
  \def\client#1{\gdef\@client{#1}}
  \def\@client{}

  \def\project#1{\gdef\@project{#1}}
  \def\@project{}

  \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
      \begin{titlepage}
          \@title

          \@project

          \@client

          \@date

          \@author
  \end{titlepage}
  }

  \makeatother

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \title{Custom class example}
  \author{Yorian}
  \date{\today}
  \project{aa}
  \client{BB}

  \begin{document}

  % Create title page
  \maketitle

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Thanks @samcarter. I thought that (based on this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) that newcommand would be preferred over def. Also, you use makeatletter, I understand this allows you to use the @ symbol in variables, but you call it twice does close the scope? Also regarding \def, are square brackets around the variable numbers optional?

Comment: @Yorian You're correct, the second `\makeatletter` should have been a `\makeatother`, but you don't need them if you use the code in a class file. I am not an expert for the comparison of newcommand/def etc, but it depends on the context. I choose `\def` to be consistent with how `\title` etc are most commonly defined. Maybe the `\gdef` is overkill ....