# best practice for consistent text snippets

Tags: best-practices

In a book document I must assure that the same text (a few lines) appears at several places, despite editing. Using the text editor to include the same text snippet does not guarantee consistency in the end.

I can do it with defininig

```
\newcommand{\partof}{\textit{part\_of}\xspace}
```

or

```
\def\verlag{my book title}
```

which seems ok for small pieces, but not for longer ones. what is the best practice? what is the difference between `newcommand` and `def`?

Comment: `\newcommand` is bullet-proof LaTeX. `\def` is *I know exactly what i am doing* TeX.

Comment: You should normally prefer `\newcommand`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/35864