# compose an array of strings as a macro

Tags: macros

I can use the `\foreach` loop to iterate over an array of strings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \v in {A, B}{
  \input{the\v file.txt}
}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to compose a string as a macro as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\var{A, B} % <<< macro
\foreach \v in \var{
  \input{the\v file.txt}
}
\end{document}
```

Then I get a problem:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `theA, Bfile.txt' not found.
```

Using `\def` instead of `\newcommand` creates the same problem using Latex version `pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)`.

How to solve?

Comment: Have you tried `\def` instead of `\newcommand`?

Comment: I do not get your error for the 2nd case.  I get the proper errors: `! LaTeX Error: File 'theAfile.txt' not found.` and `! LaTeX Error: File 'theBfile.txt' not found.` which would not occur if those files existed on my system.

Comment: You get `theA, Bfile.txt` if you call `\foreach \v in {\var}{...}`; not with your code.

Comment: @egreg, in `pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)` I have the problem without the braces `{`. In `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)` I need to add the braces to generate the problem.

Comment: Probably the relevant information is the version of TikZ. Using newer code in a very old release of TeX is hopeless; anyway, try `\expandafter\foreach\expandafter i\expandafter n\expandafter{\var}{...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with Ti*k*Z/PGF version 1.7 (2006/10/11, *twelve* years ago), but not with later versions.

I guess that, starting with version 2.0, the syntax of `\foreach` has been extended to cope with the cases

```
\foreach \v in {<list>}{...}
\foreach \v in \cs{...}
```

but the latter case was not possible in previous versions.

Solution: update your TeX system.

For the old system you can do, which will also work in newer releases, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\var{A, B} % <<< macro
\expandafter\foreach\expandafter\v\expandafter i\expandafter n\expandafter{\var}{
  \input{the\v file.txt}
}
\end{document}
```

<sup>I had to go back to TeX Live 2007, the earliest release I have on one of my machines, to reproduce the issue: `This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your `\newcommand` defines one string, so when called it produces that string.
For more about the differences, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/658/114249.
What you should use is the `\def` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \def\var{A, B} % <<< macro
    \foreach \v in \var{
        \input{the\v file.txt}
    }
\end{document}
```

This tries to open `theAfile.txt` and `theBfile.txt` as requested.

Comment: I compiled your code and got exactly the same problem.

Comment: You still get the `theA, Bfile.txt` not found, so for that exact string?

Comment: I use your code exactly.

Comment: And both of the files, so the `theAfile.txt` and `theBfile.txt` exist in the same folder as your .tex file is in? Because this does work for me...

Comment: That is using Latex version `pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)`. I succeeded to compile your code using Latex version `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`

Comment: ah, alright, so this answers your question than?

Comment: If you see my answer as a solution, could you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: Could you explain in your answer the technical clockwork why `\def` is better than `\newcommand` in this case? Also, no need to add such reminders as they are provided by the system automatically.

Comment: Compile with `\newcommand` in the latest version of pdflatex and see if it still works.

Comment: @Foitn There is no difference at all between `\newcommand{\var}{A, B}` and `\def\var{A, B}` (apart from the check done by the former and the fact that the macro it generates is `\long`, which is inessential here).

Comment: Than why does it work with `\def` and not with `\newcommand`? (Not to prove you wrong or anything, I'm really interested now)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use some package releases where `\foreach`'s list-argument must not come from a macro but must be delivered fully expanded.

If so, then something like the following might help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\OneLevelExpandedSecond[2]{%
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}%
\begin{document}
\newcommand\var{A, B} % <<< macro
\OneLevelExpandedSecond{\foreach \v in }{\var}{% <- We don't want unneeded spaces due to \endlinechar!
  \input{the\v file.txt}%  <- We don't want unneeded spaces due to \endlinechar!
}% <- We don't want unneeded spaces due to \endlinechar!
\end{document}
```