# Italics in theorem environment only for text but not for equations

Tags: equations, align, theorems, italic

I have got the following problem, I would like to keep the text in italics in my theorems but to not allow for italics in the equations (math mode, align, equation environments etc.) inside the theorem.

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\def\bs{\ensuremath\mathbf} %This command makes \bs a shortcut for \boldsymbol



\begin{document}


\begin{thm}
This is a theorem. 

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\bs{A}) = \text{Var}(\bs{Y} + \bs{X})
\end{align*}

\end{thm}

I would like to have the following in the theorem

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\bs{A}) = \text{Var}(\bs{Y} + \bs{X})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should use `\mathrm` instead of `\text`. Or better, use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}` then use `\Var`...

Comment: I agree with Phelype you're using `\text` completely wrong here. Normal users should only use `\text` for textual comments in displayed math. These are functions not comments, mark them as such.

Comment: BTW, sadly, this misuse of `\text` is very common. May I ask, where do you have it from?

Comment: Another comment with respect of the style, as suggested here: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) is better to use \newcommand instead of \def, unless you really know why are you using \def

Comment: Note that your `\bs` is definitely not a shorthand for `\boldsymbol` and, as defined, works by pure chance.

Answer (score 2):

Several errors here.

1. `[12pt]` should go between `\documentclass` and `{article}`.
2. `\def\bs{\ensuremath\mathbf}` isn't a “shorthand of `\boldsymbol`, but a wrong definition under many respects. Try it outside of math mode to see. Moreover, `\boldsymbol{X}` typesets a bold italic X, whereas `\mathbf` prints it bold upright.
3. There should be no blank line before *any* math display environment.
4. For a single equation, use `equation` (numbered) or `equation*` (unnumbered).
5. There should be no blank line between the end of a display environment and `\end{thm}`.

Now the bigger problem: `\text{Var}` is wrong, because in an italic context will print its argument in italics. You want `\operatorname{Var}` instead or `\Var` defined by

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
```

Full fixed example. I used `\rv` (random variable) instead of a more generic name; using the right semantics is helpful. I also loaded `bm` for better math boldfacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\rv}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} % random variable
% or \mathbf{#1} if you want upright type

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\begin{equation*}
\Var(\rv{A}) = \Var(\rv{Y} + \rv{X})
\end{equation*}
\end{thm}

I would like to have the following in the theorem
\begin{equation*}
\Var(\rv{A}) = \Var(\rv{Y} + \rv{X})
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]