# Changing all occurences of $x$ into X

Tags: latex-misc, tex-general

I would like to add a command to my document so that I could write 'X' in a document and it would be interpreted as '$x$' by compiler (because x is a mathematical variable that I use a lot). Can you help me?

Comment: So Xavier would become $x$avier?  Would \X be acceptable?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which LaTeX compiler -- pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, or something else? -- and which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot/should not just type X for translation. You should plan at least to type \X (better still \X{}). You will want this in the preamble of your document.

```
\newcommand{\X}{$x$}
```

Better still is below. This allows the math to be correct also in otherwise fragile commands.

```
\newcommand{\X}{\(x\)\relax}
```

The Find/Replace option in your editor is needed to make the changes in an existing document.

```
Find $x$  ... Replace with \X
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to define the macro `\def\X{\ensuremath{x}}`. It will work both in the text and in the math mode as well. See the example below

```
You can show that three times \X\ raised to the second power is
$$
    (3\X)^2 = 9 \X^2
$$
```

You'll see that it outputs something similar to

> You can show that three times *x* raised to the second power is
>
> (3 *x*)² = 9 *x*²

Comment: Please don't use `$$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Comment: What's the problem with it, @samcarter?

Comment: See the link I added to my first comment

Comment: I've seen that link even before this post, @samcarter. I use latex since 2015 and yet I feel quite new and with low level of knowledge about it. But during all my experience, I have never faced problem with either `$` or `$$`. I still don't understand why such alarm about the dollar symbols for math mode.

Comment: A single `$` sign for inline math is no problem at all (and I use it routinely), the problem is using `$$` for display math.  I think the most notable problems caused by this are inconsistent spacing and left alignment of display maths won't work.

Comment: Good. I will adopt the other methods like `\(` and `\[`. I already use `\begin{equation}` for enumerated equations. Thank you, @samcarter.

Comment: No need to use `\(`, a single `$` is fine for inline math, just don't use `$$`

Comment: See also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) for the distinction between using \newcommand and \def.

Comment: Also note that the spaces after `\X`are eaten in text mode, so the output in your example is not `x raised` but `xraised`

Comment: `zzz \X\ zzz` doesn't actually save any characters over the simpler and quicker `zzz $x$ zzz`