# How to get file name from inside a latex file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex, pdftex, biber

In the context of biblatex its possible to `bibstyle=reading`, this will produce bibliography including `abstract` and `annotation` fields.

The annotation might come from a file named like `bibannotation-TheBook2019.tex` where `TheBook2019` is the bib file entry key.

```
@book{TheBook2019,
 author     = {The Author},
 title      = {The Book Title}
}
```

The annotation file `bibannotation-TheBook2019.tex` can contain latex formated text. One might then `\input{bibannotation-TheBook2019.tex}` somewhere in a document. And so might be appropriate to include a citation in the `bibannotation-TheBook2019.tex`. Is this case it willl be self citation, I mean that file will refer to the respective entry key:

```
\cite{TheBook2019}
```

Since this information is in the file name. Can I automate it some way? So that I can just type something like:

```
\cite{\SelfCite}
```

And it will be converted to `\cite{TheBook2019}` grabbing the entry key from file name.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a couple of helper functions.

`\KcFnMiinput` saves the name of the key using `\filenametokey` then inputs the file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{TheBook2019,
 author     = {The Author},
 title      = {The Book Title}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{annotation-TheBook2019.tex}
This file contains an annotation for \verb|TheBook2019|. It's also possible to
cite it: \cite{\selfcitekey}.
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\def\filenametokey annotation-#1.tex{#1}
\newcommand{\KcFnMiinput}[1]{%
  \edef\selfcitekey{\filenametokey #1}%
  \input{#1}}
\begin{document}
\KcFnMiinput{annotation-TheBook2019.tex}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please, could you update answer so that I can also refer to bib files in another folder, like `\input{bib/bibannotation-TheBook2019.tex}`?

Comment: Can `newcommand` be used instead of `def`
? Considering https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand.

Comment: @KcFnMi It's not possible to use `\newcommand` for `\filenametokey`. It (essentially) uses the technique explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662/87678. You can modify the template however you want. Just use `\def\filenametokey bib/annotation-#1.tex{#1}` and then `\KcFnMiinput{bib/annotation-TheBook2019.tex}`. (This isn't so easy to do in the MWE though, since `filecontents` can't output to a subdirectory without `--shell-escape` to create the subdirectory first if it doesn't exist.)