# Create a form of an exercise with shadowbox

Tags: shadows

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%---- Structure Exercice -----
\newtheorem{Exc}{Exercice}
\def\exo#1{\futurelet\testchar\MaybeOptArgmyexoo}
\def\MaybeOptArgmyexoo{\ifx[\testchar \let\next\OptArgmyexoo
                        \else \let\next\NoOptArgmyexoo \fi \next}
\def\OptArgmyexoo[#1]{\begin{Exc}[#1]\normalfont}
\def\NoOptArgmyexoo{\begin{Exc}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\end{Exc}}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\exo{{}}:\\

%\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{sfaxlogo}{RGB}{127,176,206}
\colorlet{sfaxblue}{sfaxlogo!70!black!60!blue}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{{}}:

\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{{}}:

\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> How can get the exercises with the following form

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for `amsthm`, which lets you define a custom theorem style. Also, [`\newcommand` is generally favored over `\def`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand/658#658), it also allows a much cleaner definition of the behavior you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%any other packages

%---- Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont $\:$}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo

Lorem
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{: optional extra text}

Lorem
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% debut exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo

Lorem
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

See:

- [how `amsthm`'s `\newtheoremstyle` works](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Theorem_styles)
- [how to use `\newcommand` with optional arguments](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/usrguide/node18.html)
- [using a counter](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm)

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that I cannot make Lorem in a new line

Comment: You can simply add a new line at the end of the `\newtheorem`: 
`\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}\\}`

Comment: Please if I wrote ``\exo{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [(1)]
  \item [(2)]
  \item [(3)]
\end{itemize}
\finexo``, I will not obtain a new line. I hope to help me. Thanks

Comment: For environments to register as a line you need to manually have some content in the line defined by `\exo`, a hacky fix is ```\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont $\:$}```, (and no new line at the end of `\newtheorem`). There may be a more "correct" way but that should work.