# How can I shade this Venn diagram? I need to shade one more region. Any suggestions please?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can generate the following but need to modify it to include shading of the intersection of circle A and B - C. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
% Required packages
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
    set/.style = {circle,
        minimum size = 3cm,
        fill=black!30}]
% Set A
\node[set,label={135:$A$}] (A) at (0,0) {};
 
% Set B
\node[set,fill=white, label={45:$B$}] (B) at (1.8,0) {};
 
% Set C
\node[set,label=$C$] (C) at (0.9,1.5) {};
 
% Intersection
\begin{scope}
    
\clip (0,0) circle(1.5cm);
\clip (1.8,0) circle(1.5cm);
\clip (0.9,1.5) circle(1.5cm);
\fill[white!60](1.8,0) circle(1.5cm);
    
\end{scope}

% Circles outline
\draw (0,0) circle(1.5cm);
\draw (1.8,0) circle(1.5cm);
\draw (0.9,1.5) circle(1.5cm);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600474/a-subset-of-the-intersection-in-a-venn-diagram-with-tikz ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to filling of the intersection of circle A and B-C is first filling the whole figure, then filling its complement. The following code is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600490/140722), and adding a filling with `even odd rule`

```
\fill[gray!20,draw,even odd rule] \cirA \cirB;
```

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\def\r{1.5} % radius of two circles
\def\d{1}   % distance of two centers
\def\cirA{(210:\d) circle(\r)}
\def\cirB{(-30:\d) circle(\r)}
        
\draw[fill=yellow] 
\cirA +(135:\r+.3) node{$A$} 
\cirB +(45:\r+.3)  node{$B$};       
        
% Fill the complement of intersection of A and B-C
\begin{scope}
\clip \cirA;
\clip \cirB;
\draw[fill=gray!20] (90:\d) circle(\r);
\end{scope}

\fill[gray!20,draw,even odd rule] \cirA \cirB;
        
% Circles outline
\draw \cirA \cirB;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion it is humble. There is a very nice package [venndiagram](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf) of Nicola L. C. Talbot. It is very simple. Check if the diagram is correct.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillACapBNotC
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or this.....

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillACapBCapC
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know that such a package existed. Thanks, Sebastiano, for pointing it out.

Comment: @SebGlav I am happy that I have given you the possibility to know this package :-)