# Placing symbols into spreadtab

Tags: tables, symbols, calculations, spreadtab

I am quite new for the `spreadtab` package. I have prepared a MWE for my issues as:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
%\input{diagrams}
\newcommand\dollarsign{\$}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MWE}
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}}\hline
    @test1          & -                 & 200        & 300     \\
    @test2          & -                 & 200x12     & @300x12 \\
    @test3 (pcm)    & 0.99              & 1.99        & 2.99      \\\hline
    \end{spreadtab}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I cannot place a dollar sign inside the block of spreadtab as neither `0.99\$` nor `0.99\dollarsign`. On the other hand, I would like to type `200x12` inside the cell without saying `@200x12` (indicates it is text) for further column based calculation at the bottom row named as `total`. [image: Current and desired scenario] are placed here. The total row should be automatically calculated by the multiplication of test2 and test3 rows.
What are your suggestions ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One solution is adding column for $ symbols and factors as people usually do in excel.

Comment: @Zarko I got your suggestion, thanks for it. However, the size of the table increasing dramatically because of my actual case and the management is becoming more difficult to be honest :( Waiting for a bit more convenient suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: First try your table make in excel. Than you will what is possible to do. A way, as ju try to do, is dead end. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

To show the operation rather than the value, I found a workaround using the fact than `spreadtab` is made in a way that it will always compute a numerical values which is inside a command not matter what the command is.
That is why I used a `comment` command that will not display the argument taken.

For the dollar sign, the use of `:{}` (the operator used to specify what the numerical value of a cell is) solves the issue by itself. You may want to take a look at [`spreadtab` documentation](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/spreadtab/spreadtab-en.pdf) to learn a bit more about it. I also took the initiative to replace your `dollarsign` command with a `DS` command in order to enhance the readability but it does not really matter.

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
%\input{diagrams}
\newcommand\DS{\$}
\long\def\comment#1{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MWE}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}}\hline
@test1          & -                 & 200                               & 300                               \\
@test2          & -                 & $200\times12$\comment{:={200*12}} & $300\times12$\comment{:={300*12}} \\
@test3 (pcm)    & $:={0.99}\DS$     & $:={1.99}\DS$                     & $:={2.99}\DS$                     \\\hline
@total          & $:={b2*b3}\DS$    & $:={c2*c3}\DS$                    & $:={d2*d3}\DS$                    \\\hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot. Absolutely what I need. Could you also explain the line of \long\def\comment#1{}  with more details ? Is this also called \newcommand as well? Thanks @Enevevet

Comment: @ozturkib, I could have used `\newcommand{\comment}{}` (which is equivalent here in this case). `\long\def` are two primitive TeX commands while `\newcommand` was introduced in LaTeX. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116074/204085)'s a TeX.SE answer you might be interested if you want to learn about the actual dissimilarities.