# Need help creating specific Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, tikz-arrows, physics

Trying to recreate the following drawings as physics diagrams using Tikz:
[image]

I really just need help figuring out how to do the two labeled parts:

i) How to make this closed loop with arrows inside it with the one arrow passing through the center of it. No idea how to get this 3d perspective effect.

ii) This one is a bit simpler. Just need to know how to make this partial ellipse around the bar with the arrowhead at the tip

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: This is not too hard. But this site is not a `please do this for me` service. So show what you have tried, The first one can almost just be traced. I would not even bother "getting the 3D effect right"

Comment: Please don't vote to close new users' questions before they've had a chance to respond to comments.

Comment: ad i) with predefined coordinates A and B: \draw[->] (A) -- (B); similar for the "conductor" \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle; two times. Perspective: ignore 3D; remember your art classes from school, i.e. chose coordinates as needed. Ttext: \node at (Q) {i)}; ad ii) If you can do those, you can do this drawing too, perhaps without the fieldline ... but may be, when you study https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the images in the question, it is not really simple to understand how they should look like. I suggest using a graphic editor, if you do not plan to explore Ti*k*z further and then saving it as pdf. For example a very good free and open-source graphics editor can be Inkscape or GIMP.

However here are the possible solutions. For the first figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\definecolor{custom}{RGB}{234,234,230}

% square
\def\a{5}
\def\t{0.6}
% arrows
\def\l{3}
% axis
\def\axis{7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(1cm,0cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)}, even odd rule]
    % axis below
    \draw[line width = 3pt, fill] (0,-\axis,0) circle (2pt) -- (0,0,0);
    % circuit
    \filldraw[fill=custom, line width = 2pt, rounded corners]
    (\a+\t,0,-\a-\t) -- (\a+\t,0,\a+\t) -- (-\a-\t,0,\a+\t) -- (-\a-\t,0,-\a-\t) -- cycle
    (\a-\t,0,-\a+\t) -- (\a-\t,0,\a-\t) -- (-\a+\t,0,\a-\t) -- (-\a+\t,0,-\a+\t) -- cycle;
    % arrows
    \draw[-{Latex[round]},very thick] (\l,0,-\a) -- (-\l,0,-\a);
    \draw[-{Latex[round]},very thick] (-\l,0,+\a) -- (\l,0,+\a);
    \draw[-{Latex[round]},very thick] (\a,0,\l) -- (\a,0,-\l);
    \draw[-{Latex[round]},very thick] (-\a,0,-\l) -- (-\a,0,+\l);
    % axis above
    \draw[-{Stealth[round, scale = 2]}, line width = 3pt]
    (0,0,0) -- (0,\axis,0) node [above = 0.2] {\Huge $y$};
    % annotation
    \path (\a+2*\t,0,0) node [right = 0.2] {\Huge $i)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I used [`\def`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) (a TeX primitive command probably avoidable in this case) to determine some lengths.
[image: First image]

For the second figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\definecolor{custom}{RGB}{234,234,230}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(1cm,0cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(0.2cm,0.05cm)}]
    \draw[domain = 0:pi/2,smooth,thick]
    plot(0,{2*sin(\x r)},{2*cos(\x r)});
    \filldraw[thick, fill = custom]
    (-2,0.5,0) -- (3,0.5,0) -- (3,-0.5,0) -- (-2,-0.5,0);
    \draw[domain = pi/2:2*pi-pi/5,smooth,thick,-{Latex[round,scale=1.2]}]
    plot(0,{2*sin(\x r)},{2*cos(\x r)});
    \draw[thick,-{Latex[round,scale=1.2]}]
    (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0);
    \path (0,-2,0) node [right = 0.5] {\Large $ii)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you