# Showing expanded \let command with \typeout

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, debugging

I have already seen the related page [macros - What is the difference between \let and \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-edef), but I'm afraid it still doesn't expain to me the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\let\tmpa=Hello
\edef\tmpb{A\tmpa}
\tmpb           % typesets "ello AH"
\typeout{\tmpa} % writes "\tmpa" in terminal
\typeout{\tmpb} % writes "A\tmpa" in terminal
\end{document}
```

This is how I understand it:

- `\let\tmpa=` sees first character of `Hello`, `H` - it sees it as a single token and gets assigned to it (that is, `\let\tmpa=H`)
- The remaining characters ("ello") from `\let\tmpa=Hello` "fall through" and get typeset (*the "ello" in "ello AH"*)
- `\edef\tmpb{A\tmpa}` runs => since `\tmpa=H`, then `\tmpb` should expand to "AH"
- `\tmpb` runs => as expected, "AH" is typesed after the previous "ello"

And the confusion comes from \typeout{\tmpa} - from the typeset output, I'm pretty sure `\tmpa=H`; so I expect `\typeout{\tmpa}` to result with `H`, *but it doesn't* - and instead it writes again `\tmpa`! Same thing if I try to expand it via `\edef` and throw it in another command (`\tmpb`), and then I try to `\typeout` that command.

Why does `\typeout` in this case not show the "expanded" value of `\tmpa`? How can I get `\typeout` to show the expanded value of `\tmpa`?

---

Ah well, I asked this question; then I asked myself for it to be closed, given that [Showing expanded `\let` command with `\typeout`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57580/showing-expanded-let-command-with-typeout) generally provides an answer; in the meantime I came up with an answer I wanted to document - but now I cannot anymore, because it's closed `:/` So I posted the answer in [macros - How do I ‘expand’ a control sequence `\let` to a character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57583/2595); but that answer simply doesn't belong there.

Then finally I realized I can edit my question post, even if it is closed (I just cannot add an answer) - so better to delete the answer from the other question, and move it here I guess (although now that it is here, it would have been better it's an answer `:/` Ah nevermind).

So, not to nag the mods to reopen and reclose again, I'll post that answer here:

Basically, to `\typeout` the contents of that example:

- Use `\meaning` to convert `\tmpa` to "The letter H"
- Use a "parser" macro, to extract the third word from a set of three words

So finally we have the corrected MWE, that can print the content of `\tmpa` (given here we explicitly expect it to be one letter) to terminal:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\def\wordIIIofIII #1 #2 #3{#3}

\let\tmpa=Hello
\edef\tmpb{A\tmpa}
\tmpb           % typesets "ello AH"
\typeout{\tmpa} % writes "\tmpa" in terminal
\typeout{\tmpb} % writes "A\tmpa" in terminal

\edef\tmpc{\meaning\tmpa}
\typeout{\tmpc}         % writes "the letter H" in terminal
\edef\tmpd{\expandafter\wordIIIofIII\tmpc}
\typeout{\tmpd}         % writes "H" in terminal

\typeout{\the\catcode`H}                  % 11
% \typeout{\the\catcode`\tmpd} % "! Improper alphabetic constant."
\typeout{\the\catcode\expandafter`\tmpd}  %11

\end{document}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `\let` must be followed by a control sequence (or an active character), an optional `=` and *one* token! Other tokens following the first won't belong to the `\let` instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for the `\let` primitive is

```
\let<cs>=<token>
```

where `<cs>` is a control sequence or active character, `<token>` is a *single* token and `=` can be omitted or surrounded by optional spaces. So

```
\let\?=H
\let\? =H
\let\? = H
\let\?H
\let\? H
```

are all equivalent (I used `\?` so that no space is ignored in the tokenization stage).

The so defined `<cs>` inherits all the characteristics of the `<token>` (but depending on the token it may or may not be always used as a substitute). In particular, after

```
\let\tmpa=H
```

the token `\tmpa` will be unexpandable, just because `H` is unexpandable.

The command `\typeout` uses the `\write` mechanism, which does expansion, but using an output stream that is never assigned a file, so the result is written on the terminal and the log file, also adding an instruction so that `\protect` does its work correctly (for instance `\typeout{\itshape}` prints `\itshape`, while `\write255{\itshape}` would explode).

Under `\write`, unexpandable tokens are written by their name. And it's good it's this way: after `\write\@outputstream{\bgroup}`, finding out `{` in the output may be disastrous. Similarly one could have good reasons for writing out `\tmpa` instead of `H`.

The strategy with `\meaning` is correct, but it works only in this particular case and it would fail with `\bgroup`, whose meaning is

```
\bgroup=begin-group character {
```

You may find it useful to look at the `expl3` function `\tl_analysis_show:N`; compiling the following file

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\let\tmpa=H

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_analysis_show:n { \tmpa }
```

will show on the terminal

```
The token list contains the tokens:
>  \tmpa (control sequence=the letter H).
```

(For releases before TeX Live 2017, you will need `\usepackage{l3tl-analysis}` in addition to `\usepackage{expl3}` for this to work and `\tl_show_analysis:N`, now a deprecated command.)

---

Why isn't your `` \typeout{\the\catcode`\tmpd} `` working? Because an alphabetic constant is `` `<character> `` (where `<character>` may also be `<backslash><character>`) and after the backquote a multiletter control sequence is found, which is illegal.

The line `` \typeout{\the\catcode\expandafter`\tmpd} `` works, because `\catcode` expands tokens until finding something that can start a `<number>` (if not found, TeX raises an error). So the `\expandafter` is expanded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @egreg - didn't realize it was posted until now. Cheers!