# How do I reuse a command name two or more times?

Tags: macros

I found out how to [reuse a command name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85211/6480).

But how can I reuse a command more times, each time using the previous definition? If I simply try something like

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\let\oldaaa\aaa
\renewcommand{\aaa}{\oldaaa b} % now \aaa is ab
\let\oldaaa\aaa
\renewcommand{\aaa}{\oldaaa c} % now \aaa should be abc
```

I get *TeX capacity exceeded* error.

This is a very simplified example. The problem came up when I was trying to write a command that would accomplish a similar task, ie. concatenate its arguments when called repetitively; so, ideally the code should be similar for each repetition.

Comment: Your second `\let` has `\oldaaa` referencing itself by way of `\aaa`.  Remember, `\let` and `\def` are not the same.  Depending on what you are stuffing in there, replacing the first `\renewcommand` with an `\edef` should wipe the slate clean, freeing up `\oldaaa`

Comment: This is not the best way for concatenating tokens. Can you try and describe the real problem?

Comment: I accepted the answer of @Werner because it is more generic. However, for my task I used the `\appto` command suggested by @egreg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that (La)TeX is a macro programming language that has this quirky thing called "expansion". For example, if

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
```

then `\aaa` *expands* to `a`. Alternatively put, `a` is the "replacement text" for `\aaa`. In a definition of

```
\let\oldaaa\aaa
\renewcommand{\aaa}{\oldaaa b} % now \aaa is ab
```

you are copying the definition of `\aaa` into `\oldaaa` (effectively similar to `\def\oldaaa{<whatever \aaa is>}`, but *not* the same as `\def\oldaaa{\aaa}`), followed by a redefinition of `\aaa` into `\oldaaa b`. During *expansion* - when you write `\aaa`, this is replaced by `\oldaaa b`, and since you `\let\oldaaa\aaa`, this is replaced by `\aaa b`, which is circular. Here's a stepwise showcase:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\let\oldaaa\aaa
\renewcommand{\aaa}{\oldaaa b}

> \aaa
> \oldaaa b % Expansion of \aaa
> \aaa b % Expansion of \oldaaa
> \oldaaa b b % Expansion of \aaa
> \aaa b b % Expansion of \oldaaa
> \oldaaa b b b % Expansion of \aaa
> ...
```

What I think you're after is expanding the contents at the time of redefinition, which would look like this:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\aaa\expandafter{\aaa b} % now \aaa is ab
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\aaa\expandafter{\aaa c} % now \aaa should be abc
```

Note that since the replacement text of `\aaa` is *expanded* before making the assignment, so there's no need for using an additional macro like `\oldaaa`. This would also only work if the contents at redefinition is expandable itself.

Comment: And the `\let` instructions are useless: you can use `\aaa` in the redefinitions. Consider also `\appto` of `etoolbox` as a solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid `\expandafter` if you use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.  This requires the e-TeX extensions to your TeX executable, but chances are extremely high that this is default in your installation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\show\aaa
\apptocmd{\aaa}{b}{\message{aaa successfully patched}}{\message{aaa not successfully patched}}
\show\aaa
\apptocmd{\aaa}{c}{\message{aaa successfully patched}}{\message{aaa not successfully patched}}
\show\aaa
\end{document}
```

The arguments to `\apptocmd` are macro name, stuff to add to the definition, then what to do on success or failure.  I'm using the last to just to report to the console/log file that the patching succeeded or failed.  `\show` will pause compilation and write the current value of the macro to the console.  You have to hit enter to continue each time.  The result is:

```
...
> \aaa=\long macro:
->a.
l.6 \show\aaa

? [ENTER]
aaa successfully patched
> \aaa=macro:
->ab.
l.8 \show\aaa

? [ENTER]
aaa successfully patched
> \aaa=macro:
->abc.
l.10 \show\aaa

? [ENTER]
(./aaa.aux) )
No pages of output.
...
```

Comment: For parameterless macros there's the simpler `\appto`.

Comment: Good point.  You don't need the handlers for success/failure in that case.