# Can I make a "deep copy" of a macro?

Tags: macros

I would like to make a deep copy of macro that I don't have control of, because various packages might change it. So I want to take the current meaning of the macro, patching it, but without changing the original macro. Something along the lines of

```
\deepcopy\mylabel\label
\patchcmd{\mylabel}{\thepage}{\thepage+1}{}{}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `\let\mylabel\label`; however, `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package and `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` are required if the macro to copy and patch can have optional arguments or has been defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: `\let\deepcopy=\let` ;) However, `\let` is "exactly one layer deep".

Comment: @tohecz egreg Thanks. Seems I asked a stupid question. Shall I delete it?

Comment: @mafp `\let` us close it as a duplicate of [What is the difference between \let and \def?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258) or [What is the difference between \let and \edef?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8163) More information on `letltxmacro` can be found in [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001)

Comment: @mafp: Definitely _not_ a stupid question.  If one does not know about `\let` it is difficult to search for it. Having a duplicate asked in a different way may help more people get to the solution, so best to _not_ delete it.