# Copying the Label Command

Tags: macros, hyperref, labels

I want to copy the `label` command locally to preserve its use, for example when other packages might modify its behavior later on. For this reason, I would like to copy `label` using `let` (or similar) rather than `def`.

The following code works.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\NewCommandCopy{\mylabel}{\label}

\begin{document}

I tried to label here. \mylabel{test}

\newpage

I tried to reference here. \pageref{test}

\end{document}
```

However, I would also like to use `hyperref`, but it breaks things. The following code does not work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\NewCommandCopy{\mylabel}{\label}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

I tried to label here. \mylabel{test}

\newpage

I tried to reference here. \pageref{test}

\end{document}
```

More explicitly, I am getting some runaway argument error from a `hyperref` internal function.

Is there a way to copy the `label` command with `hyperref` support?

This question seems related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100591/261927), but simply using `\let` as suggested is not working for me.

Comment: Your label function doesn't produce a label as needed by hyperref.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer How would I make it do so?

Comment: Imho your plan to "preserve" the old label is simply wrong. If a package redefines \label then probably because it needs the changed definition, undoing that is bound to break something.

Comment: here you need to copy it after you have loaded hyperref you can't use the original label or pagref definitions after you load hyperref so saving them does nothing useful.

Comment: @David Carlisle I have tried copying after `hyperref` is loaded, and it gives the same error. See https://www.overleaf.com/read/jnhmqpqzynxt

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am dealing with an environment (namely, `restatable`) which kills the label function internally. I want to be able to label it anyways (I am being very careful about this).

Comment: It works for me if I put `\NewCommandCopy{\mylabel}{\label}` after begin document (ie after hyperref is set up) (you need to delete the aux file or ignore errors when you first switch) but better not to do this,

Comment: Be aware of commands like `\addtocontents` or `\@outputpage` which do `\let\label\@gobble` but which do not `\let\mylabel\@gobble`. Same with hyperef-thingies like `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes anything that patches `\label` will need to be modified to patch `\mylabel` as well. Not making the copy will certainly be preferable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Probably with `\mylabel` a mechanism is feasible where instead of the saved definition of `\label` the current `\label`-command is carried out (no matter what meaning exactly it currently has) in case `\label` does not have its usual meaning and therefore currently seems to be patched. Could turn things into confusing patchwork.

Comment: *I am dealing with an environment (namely, restatable) which kills the label function internally*  I suppose this is done because you need to ensure that duplicate labels are avoided when things are "restated".

Comment: hyperref patches both the command `\label` and the commands for cross-referencing so that more data than just page-number and value of the counter stepped as the last one before placing the label is associated to a cross-referencing-label. If you do `\NewCommandCopy{\mylabel}{\label}` before hyperref is loaded, then `\mylabel` creates cross-referencing-labels where hyperref's enlargement of the set of data handled by the cross-referencing-mechanism is not taken into account and  therefore cross-referencing-commands' extraction of data associated to a cross-referencing-label goes wrong. ...

Comment: ... associated to a cross-referencing-label goes wrong. Be aware that with many aspects of the hyperref-package things are delayed until the begin-document-hook is carried out. This is the case, e.g., with carrying out modifications to kernel-macros like `\label` and `\ref` and `\pageref`.

Comment: The main problem is that hyperref changes the number of arguments used by \newlabel which is called by \label (via the aux file).  You can always use \ref* or \pageref* to remove the hyperlink.