# Creating new primitives

Tags: macros, tex-core

Consider the following TeX:

```
\tt

~~~[def]: \meaning\def              \par
~~~[let]: \meaning\let              \par
[define]: \meaning\define           \par
~[macro]: \meaning\macro

\def\macro#1{some #1 transformation}

\let\define\def
\define\hi{hello,}

\let\let\define
\let\hello{world!}

\vskip 2ex

\centerline{
  {\hi}
  {\hello}
  {\macro{argument-based}}
}

\vskip 2ex

~~~[def]: \meaning\def              \par
~~~[let]: \meaning\let              \par
[define]: \meaning\define           \par
~~~~[hi]: \meaning\hi               \par
~[hello]: \meaning\hello            \par
~[macro]: \meaning\macro

\bye
```

which produces the output

```
   [def]:  \def
   [let]:  \let
[define]:  undefined
 [macro]:  undefined

           hello, world!  some argument-based transformation

   [def]:  \def
   [let]:  \def
[define]:  \def
    [hi]:  macro:->hello,
 [hello]:  macro:->world!
 [macro]:  macro:#1->some #1 transformation
```

I had thought that `\let` only copied that *macro* definition of a control sequence;
  is something more fundamental happening here?
In fact, I would not expect `\let` to be able to
  redirect the control sequence for primitive functions to others at *all*.
Even if `\let` is simply creating a new reference to a definition,
  as [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8242/17423) implies,
  primitives should not have 'definitions' as I understand them in the context of TeX.
Do the primitives have such 'definitions' that are simply inexpressible in TeX,
  but still able to be referenced?

---

Consider also the extended scenario:

```
\def\def{bad}
\def                \par
[def]: \meaning\def \par
[let]: \meaning\let
```

would produce

```
bad
macro:->what?
\def
```

If `\let` is doing what it says it's doing, how is `\meaning` getting a value of `\def` at all?

Comment: I am confused. What did you expect to happen? You let `\let` to `\def` and now `\let` *is* (not expands to) the primitive `\def`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I actually expected to not be able to `\let` onto a primitive, actually.  See my edit.

Comment: you can `\let` a command to anything, consider `\let\bgroup{` which defines bgroup to be an (implicit) catcode 1 brace.

Comment: Don’t forget `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` which are let to `\if<something>` every time `\<something>true` and `\<something>false` are used.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel or rather the other way round:  `\ifsomething` is let to `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do `\let<token-a>=<token-b>`, TeX creates a pointer to the memory location where `<token-b>` is stored. Primitives are stored with the name they had at the beginning of the TeX run, before the format file is loaded; there would be no other way to represent them; maybe `primitive \def` would have been better, but Knuth chose not to and to represent a primitive just with its (primitive) name. So if you do

```
\let\define\def
```

a `\show\define` will output `\define=\def` even if `\def` is redefined afterwards. Whenever `\show<token>` says `<token>=\xyz` you know that `\xyz` is a primitive and `<token>` has the same meaning as that primitive. So, in LaTeX, `\show\@@input` outputs

```
> \@@input=\input.
```

If you do

```
\let\define\def
\let\let\define
```

you make `\let` point to the same memory location `\define` points to, that is, the original memory location of `\def`. Of course you've lost the `\let` primitive, unless you saved it beforehand with `\let\primitivelet\let` (or similar). TeX follows instructions: if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, it will gladly let you to. Only some (inaccessible) tokens are protected against redefinition because one can't really access their names.

Actually, one of the aims of the LaTeX3 project is to rename *all* primitives, so as to avoid problems when a user does `\renewcommand{\box}{something}`: after saving every primitive under a new name, LaTeX3 code only uses those new names and not the original ones.

This doesn't happen with macros: if you say

```
\def\macro{replacement}
\let\newmacro\macro
```

a `\show\newmacro` will not have any trace of `\macro`. Indeed, `\macro` could then be redefined without changing the meaning of `\newmacro`.

<sub>Note: The fact that `\let\define\def\show\define` prints `\define=\def` doesn't mean that TeX remembers what `\def` is in case one also does `\define\def{Oops}`. After the `=` sign `\def` is just a representation of the meaning, not the actual command. With `pdftex` one can however access primitives by prefixing their name with `\primitive`. So `\primitive\input` will execute the primitive meaning of `\input` independently of any redefinition of `\input`.</sub>

Note that `\meaning` and `\show` are identical in this respect; the difference is that `\show` interrupts the TeX run and shows the meaning on the terminal, while `\meaning` simply prints it (TeXnically, it produces a representation of the meaning by characters of category code 12, 10 for spaces).

Comment: your next to last paragraph is misleading because its last sentence is also true of primitives: the control sequence `\def` which originally pointed to the internal meaning `\def` can be redefined without affecting any other control sequence which points to the same internal meaning.

Answer (score 11):

egreg's answer is of course correct but perhaps a bit terse. An illustrative example might help.

```
\let\let\futurelet
\let\def\let\xdef\futurelet\gdef\xdef\futurelet{}

\immediate\write20{\string\let=\meaning\let}
\immediate\write20{\string\futurelet=\meaning\futurelet}
\immediate\write20{\string\def=\meaning\def}
\immediate\write20{\string\gdef=\meaning\gdef}
\immediate\write20{\string\xdef=\meaning\xdef}

\bye
```

produces

```
\let=\futurelet
\futurelet=macro:->
\def=\xdef
\gdef=\futurelet
\xdef=\gdef
```

Comment: what a pity that `LaTeX3` takes the spice out these kind of things that the average users love to do, now that the danger will be a thing of the past!

Comment: Terse... say what?