# Expansion Issues When Passing TikZ Styles to Macro Created by Macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion, tikz-styles

I'm struggling (again) with expansions. This time I have a generic function `\misdirection` that creates a TikZ environment subject to a few options. Then, I create a macro `\freezeStyle` that creates a new macro that has frozen some of the options to `\misdirection`.  So `\freezeStyle` receives the style that I ultimately want
passed to `\misdirection`.

I tried a few `\edef`s and couldn't get it working, so I opted to put the code in a state that demonstrates something that compiles but has undesirable behavior.
This attempt was inspired by [How to submit a set of tikz command with pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85637/6896).

So: How should I modify this so that it works as desired? Please note that my actual misdirection call will involve `\csname`, so I'd appreciate expandafter solutions that also show how to adapt your solution to that case as well (see code for details).

For cross-references, here is a similar question: [Macros that write macros and unexpected side effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207572/macros-that-write-macros-and-unexpected-side-effects), with the same type of undesirable behavior, but the solution there has to do with defining customized `\csname`s, which doesn't apply to this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\misdirection}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tree) at (0,0) {tree};
    \node (apple) at (3,0) {#2};
    \draw[blue,#1] (tree) -- (apple);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/.cd,
        execute style/.style = {#1},
        execute macro/.style = {execute style/.expand once=#1},
    /demo/.cd,
        name/.store in=\savedname,
        style/.store in=\savedstyle
}

\newcommand{\freezeStyle}[1][]{%
    \pgfqkeys{/demo}{#1}
    \expandafter\def\csname\savedname\endcsname##1{%
        % Incorrect because \savedstyle is not expanded until runtime.
        % I want the value of \savedstyle hardcoded into this macro.
        \misdirection[execute macro = \savedstyle]{##1}

        % This doesn't work either...
        %\expandafter\misdirection\expandafter[\savedstyle]{##1}

        % In my real code, the misdirection call looks more like:
        %\csname someArgumentDependentStuff \endcsname[put style here]{args}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \freezeStyle[name=helloMom, style={red,thick}]
    \freezeStyle[name=helloDad, style={-{>[length=5mm]},green}]
    \helloMom{4} % Undesirably, this is green with a big arrow.
    \helloDad{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you consider an `expl3` answer for comparison?

Comment: Sure, though I can't say I'll understand it until I dig into expl3 a bit.

Comment: I added one with comments about what's going on.  It seems a bit verbose for this use, but it's a much more consistent syntax when you're dealing with more complicated cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use a "helper" macro so the `\savedstyle` can be expanded (once):

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\misdirection}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tree) at (0,0) {tree};
    \node (apple) at (3,0) {#2};
    \draw [blue,#1] (tree) -- (apple);
  \end{tikzpicture}\ignorespaces% or \par?
}

\pgfkeys{demo/.cd,
  name/.store in=\savedname,
  style/.store in=\savedstyle
}

\newcommand\freezeStyle[1][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/demo}{#1}%
  \expandafter\FreezeStyle\expandafter{\savedstyle}{\savedname}}

\def\FreezeStyle#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#2\endcsname##1{%
     \misdirection[#1]{##1}}}

\begin{document}
    \freezeStyle[name=helloMom, style={red,thick}]
    \freezeStyle[name=helloDad, style={-{>[length=5mm]},green}]
    \helloMom{4} 

    \helloDad{5}
\end{document}
```

Note, I added an `\ignorespaces` in the the `\misdirection` command.

[image]

Comment: I ended up using this one! But the other solutions are very nice as well!

Answer (score 4):

With `expl3`, just for fun :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % automatically loads expl3
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\misdirection}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tree) at (0,0) {tree};
    \node (apple) at (3,0) {#2};
    \draw[blue,#1] (tree) -- (apple);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Declare our variables; it's good practice :)
\tl_new:N \l_demo_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_demo_style_tl

% Set up our keys (`tl` is short for `token list`)
\keys_define:nn { demo } {
  name  .tl_set:N = \l_demo_name_tl,
  style .tl_set:N = \l_demo_style_tl,
}

% Create a macro to behave as if we would call
% \demo_freeze_style:Nn \helloMom { red, thick }...
\cs_new:Nn \demo_freeze_style:Nn {
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1 {
    \misdirection[#2]{##1}
  }
}
% ...but then add support for saner syntax in our use case
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \demo_freeze_style:Nn { cV }

% Now, set our keys and use our command :)
\NewDocumentCommand \freezeStyle { O{} } {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { demo } { #1 }
  \demo_freeze_style:cV { \tl_use:N \l_demo_name_tl } \l_demo_style_tl
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \freezeStyle[name=helloMom, style={red,thick}]
    \freezeStyle[name=helloDad, style={-{>[length=5mm]},green}]
    \helloMom{4}
    \helloDad{5}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'm in doubt myself here: I would `\demo_freeze_style:Nn` and then generate the `:cn` and `:cV` variants; in case you think the first argument shouldn't be `c` but `n` (as it is in your code), there is no need to `:VV`, only `:nV`. Or am I wrong? I mean, would there be any problem with using `\l_demo_name_tl` inside a `\csname …\endcsname`? Altough I see the point of using `V`.

Comment: @Manuel I would say you're spot on with making the prototype `:Nn` (since in the same vein as `\tl_const:Nn`).  I'm now a bit on the fence myself about using a `V` type argument here as well; this isn't really seen in the existing `expl3` interfaces.  No, there wouldn't be any problem at all—just more code (technically, you should wrap it with `\tl_use:N`).

Comment: @Manuel It turns out that, when used correctly, you can't go from an `N`-type to a `V`-type argument.  While the syntax was nice, it was semantically incorrect.  I've fixed that in an edit `:)` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without `expl3`:

```
\newcommand\freezeStyle[1][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/demo}{#1}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\savedname\endcsname##1{%
    \noexpand\misdirection[\savedstyle]{##1}}}
```

Note that `\edef` is used here and `\noexpand` is used to protect macros that should not be expanded.

```
\typeout{\meaning\helloMom}
macro:#1->\misdirection [execute macro=red,thick]{#1}
```

---

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfkeys{
    /demo/.cd,
        name/.store in=\savedname,
        style/.store in=\savedstyle
}

\newcommand{\misdirection}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tree) at (0,0) {tree};
    \node (apple) at (3,0) {#2};
    \draw[blue,#1] (tree) -- (apple);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\freezeStyle[1][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/demo}{#1}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\savedname\endcsname##1{%
    \noexpand\misdirection[\savedstyle]{##1}}}

\begin{document}
    \freezeStyle[name=helloMom, style={red,thick}]
    \freezeStyle[name=helloDad, style={-{>[length=5mm]},green}]
    \helloMom{4}
    \helloDad{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. So if I'm understanding this now, I shouldn't even need to have `execute macro=` in there. Just: `\noexpand\misdirection[\savedstyle]{##1}}}`

Comment: @Tom Whoops, yes, you're right :)