# Redefining line break (double backslash) for align environment

Tags: line-breaking, amsmath, tex-core

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to (locally) redefine \\ (double backslash) within amsmath's align environment. On the one hand, I'd like to be able to dynamically insert extra columns, on the other I'd like to manipulate spacing. Here is an example, which does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\renewcommand{\\}{& x \\[1cm]}%
1  \\
2  \\
3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The adapted \\ is active for the first line but seems to be reset afterwards so the output is

```
1x


2
3
```

Redefining the command once again after the first line makes it active for the second but stops again working after the second line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\renewcommand{\\}{& x \\[1cm]}%
1  \\ \renewcommand{\\}{& x \\[1cm]}%
2  \\
3  \\
4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, if I first store away the original \\ and use that in my redefinition

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\let\mylb\\
\begin{align*}
\renewcommand{\\}{& x \mylb[1cm]}%
1  \\ 
2  \\
3  \\
4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

the result is not quite what I hoped for as this seems just to swallow up the linebreak:

```
1x2 
3
4
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `align` environment (with or without star) is internally implemented via a table (`\halign` is the TeX primitive). Each cell is inside a group. Therefore local definitions are lost after the cell.

Also I would not want to mess with `\\` by global definitions. Equations could also occur inside other environments (`center`, `flushleft`, ...), which also redefine `\\` locally. Global redefinitions would destroy the re-establishing of the previous meaning after such an environment.

The following example solves the issue by using a different command name `\NL`. The global redefinitions are done in `\noalign` before the new row starts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\gdef\NL{\\}
\begin{align*}
  a\NL
  b\NL
  \noalign{\gdef\NL{& x \\[1cm]}}%
  1 \NL
  2 \NL
  3 \NL
  \noalign{\gdef\NL{\\}}%
  c \NL
  d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behavior. I was, however, rather hoping not having to work with a different macro but redefine \\ for the scope of one align. I've originally placed it doing something like \let\mylb\\\renewcommand{\\}{& x \mylb}\begin{align*}1  \\ 2  \\ 3\end{align*} did not seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: On second thoughts .. the tip with halign does it. That is, when redefining halign locally I am able to get the effect that I was going for.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness. Heiko's pointer to halign allows to implement the effect I was going for. Here is the short code snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\myhalign\halign
\def\halign{%
\let\mylb\\
\renewcommand{\\}{& x \mylb[1cm]}
\myhalign
}
\begin{align*}
1  \\ 
2  \\
3
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\begin{align*}
1  \\ 
2  \\
3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here I was able to redefine \\ for the first align without changing other aligns. The output of the above is:

```
1x


2x


3



1
2
3
```

Comment: Could I ask some small questions? 1. With only `\let\mylb\\ \renewcommand{\\}{& x \mylb[1cm]}` it only works for text instead of the `align*` block. What causes this weird result? 2. With yours, only `align*` but not text works. After some search especially https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383381/308105, I know `\let` will make `\myhalign` expansion same as `\halign`. Then the above means `\let\myhalign\let\mylb\\...\myhalign` which is nested. So how does this nested block make `\\` in the `align*` block work?