# Measure remaining space on page and use it on another page

Tags: spacing, macros

I want to measure the remaining space and use that number on another page. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Firstpage}

\lipsum[1-4]

\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}

%%The value seems to be calculated correctly
\the\measurepage

\newpage

\section*{Secondpage}
%% Skip the measured space from the page before

\vfill

%%This is not the value stored above
\the\measurepage

\begin{minipage}[t][\measurepage][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}` and use it `\measurepage`

Comment: note that any such calculation is only approximate: tex's page breaker acts at a different time long after that value is calculated

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There ie no way to converge to the appropriate value after 1 or 2 compilations? I tried to add `\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax}\rule{1mm}{\measurepage}` and it is always moved to the next page if I don't also substract a small number like 3pt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For more details

[What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

[What is the difference between \let and \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-edef)

A solution is to use `\edef` method

```
\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Firstpage}

\lipsum[1-4]

\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}

%%The value seems to be calculated correctly
\measurepage

\newpage

\section*{Secondpage}
%% Skip the measured space from the page before

\vfill

%%This is not the value stored above
\measurepage

\begin{minipage}[t][\measurepage][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This might work too.  I use the existing definition of `\measurepage`, but set a new length, `\remainder`, to its value.  I then use `\remainder` in the `minipage` argument.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength\remainder
\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
\begin{document}

\section*{Firstpage}

\lipsum[1-4]


%%The value seems to be calculated correctly
\remainder=\measurepage\relax\the\remainder

\newpage

\section*{Secondpage}
%% Skip the measured space from the page before

\vfill

%%This is not the value stored above
\the\measurepage

\begin{minipage}[t][\remainder][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get more exact values by storing the actuall positions in the aux-file. This need two compilations (the x are only there to show the locations):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\begin{document}

\section*{Firstpage}

\lipsum[1-4]

x\zsavepos{start}\par\vfill\mbox{x}\zsavepos{end}

\newpage

\section*{Secondpage}
%% Skip the measured space from the page before

\vfill

%the y position has its zero at the bottom
\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\zposy{start}sp-\zposy{end}sp][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]\vfill xxxx
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]