# Enclosing leaders by a border/frame

Tags: macros, tcolorbox, mdframed, xparse, leaders

Following-up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525552/2288), how can I edit the command `\FillAnswerRules` to enclose the leaders by a border/frame by using `tocolorbox` or `mdframed` so that I can get the same output of `\CountAnswerRules`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xparse,xcolor,tcolorbox,mdframed,pgffor,blindtext}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0\baselineskip}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    num-lines .int_set:N = \l_diaa_answers_numlines_int ,
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    num-lines .initial:n = 3,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \group_begin:
    \par
    \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
    \leaders \hbox:n
    {
        \makebox[\textwidth][s]{
            \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
            \vrule width 0pt height \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim % the distance
            \leaders\hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim\hfill
        }
    }\vfill
    \clearpage
    \group_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CountAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }

    \begin{mdframed}[
        innerrightmargin = 10pt, innertopmargin = 20pt,
        innerleftmargin = 10pt, innerbottommargin = 20pt,
        leftmargin = 0pt,
        rightmargin = 0pt,
        linecolor=black, linewidth = 2pt]

        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\l_diaa_answers_numlines_int} {\color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}%
            \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim}\par
        }

    \end{mdframed}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question short question \CountAnswerRules[d = 20pt]
        \question \blindtext[1]\FillAnswerRules[t = 1pt]
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tcolorbox` `height fill` and `text fill` options for this. In the code below, I wrap the `\FillAnswerRules` leaders inside a `tcolorbox` environment defined by:

```latex
\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
  {
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
  }
```

The tildes (`~`) stand for spaces here, because I do this between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`; otherwise, you would use normal spaces instead of the tildes. Note that I specified the option `sharp corners` to perfectly match the appearance of the `mdframed` box, but the `tcolorbox` default with rounded corners looks better in my opinion.

I also modified the code inside the outer leaders so that the upper rule inside the box doesn't start too far from the top of the box and the lower rule doesn't come too close to the bottom of the box. This corresponds to the following lines:

```latex
\vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
       depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
\leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
```

Here is the full code:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor,tcolorbox,mdframed,pgffor,blindtext}
% The tcolorbox library 'breakable' is needed for /tcb/height fill; 'xparse' is
% not necessary here, but convenient and powerful (the use of \NewTColorBox
% may prove useful for future evolutions of the code).
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, xparse}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0\baselineskip}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    num-lines .int_set:N = \l_diaa_answers_numlines_int ,
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    num-lines .initial:n = 3,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
  {
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
  \begin{fillAnswerRules}
    \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
    \leaders \hbox:n
      {
        \makebox[\textwidth][s]
          {
            \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
            % Vertically center the following \leaders inside a “line” that
            % is \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim high.
            \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                   depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
            \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
          }
      }\vfill
    \null
  \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CountAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }

    \begin{mdframed}[
        innerrightmargin = 10pt, innertopmargin = 20pt,
        innerleftmargin = 10pt, innerbottommargin = 20pt,
        leftmargin = 0pt,
        rightmargin = 0pt,
        linecolor=black, linewidth = 2pt]

        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\l_diaa_answers_numlines_int}
          {
            \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
            \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim}\par
          }

    \end{mdframed}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Short question \CountAnswerRules[d=20pt, t=1pt]
    \question \blindtext[1]\FillAnswerRules[d=20pt, t=1pt]
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace:

```latex
\vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
       depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
```

with the original

```latex
\vrule width 0pt height \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
```

the second box looks like this:

[image]

If you further remove the `top=8pt, bottom=0pt` from the `...` options of the `\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} } {...}`, the second box becomes:

[image]

The full example looks better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I would like to understand more how technically setting both the height and the depth to half the spacing each helps get the preferred output layout. Would you recommend me an answer that **graphically** explains the role of each one?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Basically, in the original code, each rule is at baseline level, there is a full height of `\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim` - `\l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim` above it and no space below it. With my change, vertical blank space is more equally spread around each rule.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I found out that setting `bottom = 0.25 <spacing> , top = 0pt` with `depth = 0pt` yields better eye-comforting layout for me.