# Re-defining a variable w.r.t itself a finite number of times

Tags: macros, recursion

Is there any way to re-define a variable a finite number of times? Here's MWE of what I'm looking for to work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\A}{..}
\newcommand{\B}{../\A{}}
% \renewcommand{\A}{\B{}}    % Breaks the build
\newcommand{\SUCCESS}{Success!}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\A
\B
\SS
\end{document}
```

When I uncomment line 4, I get an error saying "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. [\A]".

I was hoping to do this in a simple way, without packages. If I remove the curly-braces in the definition for \B and re-definition for \A, the build hangs and never seems to finish.

I appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: This is a clear infinite loop. What's your precise goal?

Comment: I would like to prepend ../ to \A.

Comment: @Charlie: You can do `\newcommand{\A}{..} \edef\A{../\A} ... \edef\A{../\A} ...`

Comment: Well, I had been searching for a while, but I just now found this solution, which seems most appropriate... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-edef

Comment: Thank you @Werner, that's precisely what I'm going with.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to prepend `../` to whatever `\A` expands to, the answer is with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\A}{..whatever..}

\begin{document}

\A %% prints ..whatever..

\preto{\A}{../}

\A %% prints ../..whatever..

\end{document}
```

Without `etoolbox`, the standard way is

```
\toks0={../}
\toks2=\expandafter{\A}
\edef\A{\the\toks0 \the\toks2 }
```

About the error you get if you do

```
\newcommand{\A}{..}
\newcommand{\B}{../\A}
\renewcommand{\A}{\B}
```

here's the explanation. When you eventually call `\A`, TeX will replace it with `\B`, which will be replaced with `../\A`. Now `../` are processed and macro expansion restarts from `\A`. Infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way but I don't know what it supposed to do.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\A}{..}
\let\oldA\A
\newcommand{\B}{../\oldA{}}
\renewcommand{\A}{\B{}}    % Now DOESN'T break the build
\newcommand{\SUCCESS}{Success!}


\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\A
\B
\SUCCESS

\end{document}
```

The solution is to keep the old definition of the command with the help of a `\let` command and use this instead of the original , so that redefined command (`\A`) doen't call itself.