# Redefining \verb to be \url

Tags: verbatim

How can I redefine `\verb!!` to translate into `\url{}`? I have to do this to fool Emacs highlighting so it thinks I have `\verb`, in the background I like `\url{}` wrapping capability.

Comment: `\let\verb\url`?!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this is only so your editor (Emacs) is happy in some way, or is this actually about the LaTeX output you get?

Comment: I could not find a way to make Emacs highlight \url the way \verb is highlighted, so I fixed it on the Latex side. It is a hack, big time, but it works now.

Comment: I think that if you asked **How to get Emacs properly highlight \url**, you would get a sufficient answer. This is, in my opinion, a typical example of the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you apparently asked the wrong question (see tohecz's comment) it's solution  is

```
\let\verb\url
```

See for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258/5049) and its answers for an explanation of `\let`.