# use lining figures in references

Tags: fonts, cross-referencing, libertine

I use lowercase/old style figures in most of my document, but want to use uppercase/lining figures in references (as they're "proper nouns" I think).  I'm using the following at the moment:

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\liningfigures{\ref{#1}}}
```

(`\liningfigures` comes from `fontaxes` with `libertine` fonts) but that means that I have to use `\myref{id}` all over the place.  I was wondering what to use so that I can just use `\ref` as normal.

Hum, while looking for the right terms I found out how to do it.  Will post my answer below… if anyone has a better way to do it, feel free to contribute!

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as capturing the definition of `\ref` using `\let` and using it in the new definition:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand*\ref[1]{\liningfigures{\oldref{#1}}}
```

For more details, see: [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)

Comment: This might fail if `hyperref` is loaded. It's better to use `\LetLtxMacro\oldref\ref` (with `\usepackage{letltxmacro}). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro

Comment: I'd already been using `hyperref` in my document, with no obvious ill effects.  Will use `LetLtxMacro` though.