# How to store a counter value at some point in the document?

Tags: macros, counters

I'm beginning to learn LaTeX and I need some help with counters.

My goal is to store the value a certain counter reaches at some point in the document and use it later. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

text
\let\myvalue\thesection

\section{title}
text

\myvalue

\end{document}
```

but `\myvalue` prints 2 instead of 1.

I read this: [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def) but let does not seem to store the value at the definition time in my case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well that is expected as you are calling `\myvalue` after the second section. The declaration `\let\myvalue\thesection` is just the definition of what `\myvalue` is. I suppose you want something similar to the referencing command.

Comment: could you make an example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you need `\myvalue` for? If it's for saying something like “As we say in Section 1”, then you should add `\label{sec:whatever}` (with a more meaningful string instead of `sec:whatever`, of course) and say, when you need it, `As we saw in Section~\ref{sec:whatever}`.

Comment: I need it to restart the counter from the given value at some later point without having to count how many steps there have been. The proposed solution is more than enough, thank you all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A naive example of how to do that,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

text
\setcounter{foo}{\value{section}}

\section{title}
text

\thefoo

\end{document}
```

You just create a new counter with the command `\newcounter` and you set it to the value you want with `\setcounter`.

[image: Output]

**NOTE** If you re looking for some referencing tool, better solutions exist with `\label{}` and `\ref{}`, among other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\label{sec:mylabel}

text
\setcounter{foo}{\value{section}}

\section{title}

This is using the new counter: \thefoo

\noindent
This is using the label and ref commands: \ref{sec:mylabel}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output 2]

Comment: yes, this is it. I was sure that I had already tried this! Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can also use `\edef` but not `\def` as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\section{Andy}
Saving \ldots
\edef\fixed{\thesection}
\def\notfixed{\thesection}

\section{Billy}
fixed: \fixed\ and notfixed: \notfixed

\section{Charlie}
fixed: \fixed\ and notfixed: \notfixed
\end{document}
```

[image]