# Aliasing, with or without argument?

Tags: macros

What is the correct way to alias a command to another one?

```
\newcommand*{\keyword}{\emph}
```

or:

```
\newcommand*{\keyword}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

Apart from the fact that the second is more explicit, is there any real
differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference will arise when the *aliased* command takes an optional argument.

```
\newcommand*\keyword{\othercommand}
```

will be able to handle any possible optional arguments.  But

```
\newcommand*\keyword[1]{\othercommand{#1}}
```

will only be able to handle the situation where `\othercommand` is called without an optional argument.

In the case of `\emph`, this is not an issue as there is no optional argument to be taken there.  So either approach should work fine.

When you are just strictly *aliasing*,
my personal opinion would be to use the first

```
\newcommand*\keyword{\othercommand}
```

In a situation where I'm doing something more than just aliasing,
I would use

```
\newcommand*\keyword[1]{\othercommand{#1}}
```

Purely for example's sake,

```
\newcommand*\keyword[1]{`\emph{#1}'}
```

(though others will most likely object that the quotes are unnecessary to `\emph`
I only mean this as an illustration of what "more than just aliasing" might mean.)

**Letting**

Since this has come up in the comments, I'll mention a few things about `\let`ting a command.

Sometimes you want to change the default behavior of a LaTeX macro.  For example, suppose there is a macro defined as

```
\newcommand*\somecommand[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

but you would like it to behave differently.  Then you could simply rewrite it as follows:

```
\renewcommand*\somecommand[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

But then you might run into a situation where you would really like to have the original definition.  In that case, before *renewing* the command, you could do something like

```
\let\oldsomecommand\somecommand
\renewcommand*\somecommand[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Now `\somecommand` will behave as you wish, but you also have `\oldsomecommand` as an available command to give you the old behavior.

In a nut shell, by writing `\newcommand\keyword{\emph}`, `\keyword` will expand to `\emph`.  By writing `\let\keyword\emph`, `\keyword` will expand, not to `\emph`, but to the definition of `\emph`.

However, `\let` is not always able to capture the full power of a command that's been *blessed/cursed* with optional arguments.  There are many posts on this site about how to handle such situations so I'll point you to just a few here:

- See [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258/22413) for the basic gist of it.
- See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/22413) for a detailed explanation of `\let`ting working around issues involving options.
- Also see [“Closed” (square) root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/22413) (even though the original question isn't really about `\let`ting.)

Comment: Why not `\let`ting it?

Comment: @percusse True enough.  But a `\let` command does not always handle optional arguments correctly considering the different means of implementing optional arguments.

Comment: @percusse Because `\let` is not a documented command in the LaTeX manual.

Comment: @egreg Does this mean, that one shouldn't have `\let` in his document at all?

Comment: @shilluc, I'm certain that's not at all what egreg meant.  I suspect it's a bit more tongue in cheek than anything else.

Comment: @egreg OK `\LetLtxMacro`then?

Comment: @percusse No need for it except in programming; simple aliasing is best done with `\newcommand`, in my opinion.