# changes to .sty code in TeX paper directly

Tags: packages, back-referencing

I wish to change a line from the  Heiko Oberdiek's `backref.sty` in my document directly. The line reads:

```
\long\def\hyper@page@backref#1#2#3{\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
```

I have something to add there:

```
\long\def\hyper@page@backref#1#2#3{(cited on page \hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}$\uparrow$)}
```

It works pretty well in `backref.sty`, but is ignored when put into my document. I do not want to export edited `.sty` files with such a small change to other local machines, where my document is supposed to be compiled.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer a full document where this feature occurs in order to provide help. A single line of code is not helpful in most cases. Please show what you have done so far. An 'ordinary' patch should work eventually. I can imagine also that this after to put into `\AtBeginDocument{...}`

Comment: if you put that line in the preamble you need to surround it with `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`

Answer (score 1):

While your wish does not seem to make sense to me if I try to understand it literally, my guess is that the problem you are experiencing is the following:

From a quick glance at `backref.sty`, the macro `\hyper@page@backref` seems to be used only once: If the option `hyperpageref` is set, then `\hyper@page@backref` is copied to `\backrefxxx` using `\let` (see [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)).  Thus, the problem is the following: When you call `\usepackage`, then `\hyper@page@backref` is defined, and its value is copied to `\backrefxxx` immediately.  When you change `\hyper@page@backref` later, this has no effect, since `\hyper@page@backref` is not used anymore.

You could try to redefine `\backrefxxx` directly (but I did not try that).