# Can I reobtain a command I've overwritten with renewcommand?

Tags: macros

I've overwritten the `\bullet` command using `\renewcommand` (which in hindsight, was a bad idea...). After using the new `\bullet` command for quite a while, I've realized that it behaves badly in certain situations.

Preferably, I would like to define a new command `\bulleto` which is just the old `\bullet` command and keep the new `\bullet` command. Is there any way to do this? I've tried to put `\newcommand{\bulleto}{\bullet}` in front of the `\renewcommand{\bullet}{..}`. But sadly then `\bulleto` uses the new version of bullet (which isn't really unexpected)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\let\bulleto\bullet` to preserve the old meaning *before* you use `\renewcommand` to redefine it. See also

[What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)

Comment: however before `\renewcommand\bullet{...}`   :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Right, edited. :)