# pgfplots: using a list generated with \foreach as symbolic coords

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create some bar charts using pgfplots. Each chart will have a similar format, but with some different labels and values. I am trying to make a command that will generate my chart from this input data. For example, I would like to be able to type `\drawchart{Foo/10, Bar/20}` and have this produce an appropriate bar chart. I'm having trouble taking this input "Foo/10, Bar/20" and converting it into a list "Foo,Bar" that `symbolic coords` can use. Here is a MWE, that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\def\lab{Foo,Bar}
\let\labb\lab

\def\ylabelscmd{\foreach \label/\val in {Foo/1,Bar/2} {{\label},}}
\global\let\ylabels\ylabelscmd


\begin{document}
\ylabelscmd --- \ylabels
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            %symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\lab}, % works
            %symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\labb}, % works
            %symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\ylabelscmd}, % error: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
            symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\ylabels}, % error: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
            ytick = data,
            ]
            \addplot+ coordinates { (1,Foo) (2,Bar) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, it works if the command in the `symbolic coords` is a hard-coded list, but if I generate it using `\foreach` it complains. As you can see in the code, I've tried to evaluate the command using `\let` and using that, but it seems to make no difference (at least with the `expand once` option).

Any ideas?

Comment: I have different error when compiling your code `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate 'Foo' has not been defined with 'symbolic y coords={\foreach \label /\val in {Foo/1,Bar/2} {{\label },}}
... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]Fo
o?.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess all you want is to store the symbolic coordinate list in `\ylabels`. In order to achive that you can use `\xdef` as in my code below.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\def\lab{Foo,Bar}
\let\labb\lab

% use this to store the result of your for loop to \ylabelscmd
\def\ylabelscmd{}
\foreach \label/\val in {Foo/1,Bar/2}{\xdef\ylabelscmd{\ylabelscmd,\label}}

\global\let\ylabels=\ylabelscmd


\begin{document}
\ylabelscmd --- \ylabels

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            %symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\lab}, % works
            %symbolic y coords/.expanded = {\labb}, % works
            %symbolic y coords/.expand once = {\ylabelscmd}, % error: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
            symbolic y coords/.expand once={\ylabels}, % error: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
            ytick = data,
            ]
            \addplot+ coordinates { (1,Foo) (2,Bar) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks -- this does just what I want.I don't quite understand why the original code I posted doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with expansion/evaluation, but I was under the impression that the `\let` version of the command should have expanded the command and evaluate it at the time of `\letting`.

Comment: As I understand, `\let` doesn't  expand anything, it is just an alias: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def . You can try to put the whole `for loop` inside the axis option `symbolic y coords/.expand once={\foreach ...}`, it doesn't work too. Even if you use `expanded` instead of `expand once`, it still doesn't work. I guess it is related to how `pgffor` behaves. I am not sure.